# Remove tracking branches no longer on remote

Tags: git, git-branch

Is there a simple way to delete all tracking branches whose remote equivalent no longer exists?

Example:

Branches (local and remote)

- master
- origin/master
- origin/bug-fix-a
- origin/bug-fix-b
- origin/bug-fix-c

Locally, I only have a master branch. Now I need to work on *bug-fix-a*, so I check it out, work on it, and push changes to the remote. Next I do the same with *bug-fix-b*.

Branches (local and remote)

- master
- bug-fix-a
- bug-fix-b
- origin/master
- origin/bug-fix-a
- origin/bug-fix-b
- origin/bug-fix-c

Now I have local branches *master*, *bug-fix-a*, *bug-fix-b*. The Master branch maintainer will merge my changes into *master* and delete all branches he has already merged.

So the current state is now:

Branches (local and remote)

- master
- bug-fix-a
- bug-fix-b
- origin/master
- origin/bug-fix-c

Now I would like to call some command to delete branches (in this case *bug-fix-a*, *bug-fix-b*), which are no longer represented in the remote repository.

It would be something like the existing command `git remote prune origin`, but more like `git local prune origin`.

Comment: Why do majority of answers answer: "Delete branches that have been merged", when the question is specifically for "branches no longer on remote". This is a pretty big difference.

Comment: @pijemcolu because the remote branch may be deleted, not only merged

Answer (score 2144, accepted):

`git remote prune origin` prunes tracking branches not on the remote.

`git branch --merged` lists branches that have been merged into the current branch.

`xargs git branch -d` deletes branches listed on standard input.

Be careful deleting branches listed by `git branch --merged`. The list could include `master` or other branches you'd prefer not to delete.

To give yourself the opportunity to edit the list before deleting branches, you could do the following in one line:

```
git branch --merged >/tmp/merged-branches && \
  vi /tmp/merged-branches && xargs git branch -d </tmp/merged-branches
```

Comment: The first line of the merged branches is `* master` on my system. The following command worked for me: `git branch -d $(git branch --merged |tail -n +2)`

Comment: If I'm on `develop` then `git branch --merged` includes `master`!  You probably (definitely!) don't want to delete that.  Also I think it should be `git branch -d` where lowercase `-d` means "safe delete" e.g. only delete if merged.

Comment: It seems an improved solution is provided [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16906759/490018).

Comment: Removed merged is useful, but not the same as "remove branches not on remote."

Comment: Somehow for me this also tries to delete branches that have the same names as all my root directories and files. Any way to exclude those?

Comment: This just deleted master for me. Perhaps the advice should be `git checkout master; git branch...`?

Comment: Please update this answer git branch -d $(git branch --merged) should not be used as it deletes all merged branches including master... this is not the intended behavior asked by the OP... Ideally branches which have been deleted in the remote should be the only ones deleted

Comment: This does not remove deleted (without merging) branches.  It also removes master.

Comment: Just use grep to exclude master:
`git branch --merged | grep -v "master" >/tmp/merged-branches && vi /tmp/merged-branches && xargs git branch -d </tmp/merged-branches`

Comment: To delete all branches but "master" and "develop" you can use: `git branch --merged | sed '/^\** *develop$/d' | sed '/^\** *master$/d' | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: You can also use moreutils `vipe` to do the same as `git branch --merged >/tmp/merged-branches && vi /tmp/merged-branches && xargs git branch -d </tmp/merged-branches`  eg. `git branch --merged | vipe | xargs git branch -d` https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/

Comment: Why not deleting the temp file at the end ?
``git branch --merged >/tmp/merged-branches && vi /tmp/merged-branches && xargs git branch -d </tmp/merged-branches && rm /tmp/merged-branches``

Comment: If this can help, here is my favorite one-liner without intermediate files:

`git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|develop)" | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: My more aggressive version, if it helps someone: `git branch --format "%(refname:short)" >/tmp/merged-branches && vim /tmp/merged-branches && xargs git branch -D </tmp/merged-branches`

Comment: Consider an explicit branch - eg. `git branch --merged origin/develop` - so that this command is agnostic to the current checkout.

Comment: Use either the command line or the git bash to run these commands. The built in terminals might not work.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Hi there, future me: When will you finally make an alias command for this, huh?

Comment: @thom_nic I'm not sure what's the big deal with deleting local master branch. The workflow people usually use is they have named branches per task they work on. `master` is usually unused. Well, ofc one has to rebase upon the remote master branch, but that would be a `upstream/master` *(or whatever you call your upstream remote)*. I even have a git alias `git newbranch` that uses `upstream/master`. No need to use an excess local master branch. As an example, the master branches in projects I work on aren't updated in ages. Do you use a different workflow?

Comment: `git remote prune origin` can now be [automated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049939/4995828).

Comment: For me the best way is.
`git remote prune origin | git branch -d $(git branch --merged | grep -v 'develop' | grep -v 'master')
`
It works nice

Comment: Here is a solution which will keep main and works with Powershell:
`git branch --merged |Where-Object {$_ -notlike "*main"}| ForEach-Object{git branch -d $_.Trim()}`

Comment: This doesn't work if you use the merge target as the tracking branch. Instead this will actually check if the remote branch is gone after pruning: `for b in $(git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname:short)'); do git show-ref --quiet "origin/$b" || git branch -D "$b"; done`

Comment: We using working branch names that incorporate each developer's username, so this works pretty well for me: `git branch | grep username | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: short way: `git branch --merged | grep -v develop | grep -v master | xargs git branch -d`

Answer (score 1285):

The safest way to do this is to use the "plumbing" command `git for-each-ref` with the interpolation variable `%(upstream:track)`, which will be `[gone]` when the branch is no longer on the remote:

```
git fetch -p && for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads | awk '$2 == "[gone]" {sub("refs/heads/", "", $1); print $1}'); do git branch -D $branch; done
```

This approach is somewhat safer than using the "porcelain" command, because there is no risk of accidentally matching on part of the commit message. Here is a version using the "porcelain" git commands:

```
git fetch -p && for branch in $(git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}'); do git branch -D $branch; done
```

The way this works is that after the command

```
git fetch -p
```

removes the remote references, when you run

```
git branch -vv
```

it will show 'gone' as the remote status. For example,

```
$ git branch -vv
  master                 b900de9 [origin/master: behind 4] Fixed bug
  release/v3.8           fdd2f4e [origin/release/v3.8: behind 2] Fixed bug
  release/v3.9           0d680d0 [origin/release/v3.9: behind 2] Updated comments
  bug/1234               57379e4 [origin/bug/1234: gone] Fixed bug
```

This is what the scripts iterate over.

Comment: @KrzysztofWende - not on Solaris and some BSDs and some OS X :)

Comment: It looks like this will also remove any branch that has "gone" in the last commit message.

Comment: @dlsso If the last commit message contains the string ": gone]" then yes it will be removed as well. You can make it more robust at the expense of simplicity by having an additional awk/gawk to strip off the commit message. `git branch -vv | gawk '{print $1,$4}' | grep 'gone]' | gawk '{print $1}'`

Comment: The script in the answer worked for me but with an odd twist. It returned all of the file and folder names in addition to branch names. I ran this in the bash shell that was included with git (downloaded from Atlassian along with SourceTree). I think it is some kind of quirk in the shell because the script looks perfectly fine to me. But it would interesting to know if anybody else saw this.

Comment: In reply to my previous comment (question), the current branch has \* as the first field. If it happens to also be in the list of "gone" branches, $1 will be assigned \* and will be interpreted as a filespec with awk spitting out file and folder names. I eliminated the grep expression and had awk do all of the filtering: `awk '/: gone]/{if ($1!="*") print $1}'`. This now works as expected.

Comment: it would be better to do `git branch -d` to delete a fully merged branch

Comment: `git fetch -p &&git branch -vv|grep ': gone]'|awk '{print $1}'|xargs git branch -D`

Comment: I tried to add the script to gitconfig file as an alias but the after executing the alias it return `fatal: Invalid refspec ': disparue]'
`

Comment: @ahmedbhs what does your complete alias line look like?

Comment: I addede this line into gitconfig ```test  = 'git fetch -p && for branch in `git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}'`; do git branch -D $branch; done'``` then I got this error when I try to execute `git test` `fatal: Invalid refspec ': gone]'`

Comment: @ahmedbhs since the command uses single quote ' you need to use double quote " to surround the entire command. Also, git aliases that are shell commands (like this one) require ! at the beginning. This works for me: `test = "!git fetch -p && for branch in \`git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}'\`; do git branch -D $branch; done"`

Comment: Can you explain to me the story of adding `!` to the bash command, any online reference that explain the trick plz

Comment: Here's a more definitive but less informative source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Comment: Here's a more informative but less definitive source: https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/advanced-git-aliases

Comment: my version: ```git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 echo git branch -d```

Comment: As mentioned by @fiorentinoing, I would rather use `-d` than `-D`, in order to keep not-yet-merged branches that might still hold some valuable, albeit possibly experimental, code.
I'll add to the bikeshedding here with my own spin of it: `git branch -v|grep gone|awk '{print $1}'| xargs git branch -d`

Comment: How about using "cut" to remove the * before the checked-out branch? I.e. `git branch -vv | cut -c 3- | gawk '{print $1,$4}' | grep 'gone]' | gawk '{print $1}'`?

Comment: No, this still doesn't work if the second word of the commit comment is "gone]".

Comment: @MarcelloRomani use of `-d` and `-D` depends on context: git doesn't detect merged branches via "squash and merge" in GH.

Comment: Yes, but it would require that the develop or master branch be tracking a remote branch that was deleted. With typical develop/master workflows, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @jason.rickman, more robust - and more efficient - is to filter in `awk` directly: `git branch -vv | awk '$4 = "gone]" {print $1}'`.

Comment: Fish shell version: `git fetch -p && for branch in (git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads | awk '$2 == "[gone]" {sub("refs/heads/", "", $1); print $1}'); git branch -D $branch; end`

Comment: I've put together a `bash` snippet, hope it can be useful to others as well. It `dry-run`s by default, requires `--delete` to actually remove branches: https://github.com/marcelloromani/scratchpad/blob/master/bash_profile_snippets/git_delete_gone_branches.sh

Comment: you could also `git fetch -p && for branch in $(git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}'); do git branch -D $branch; done` – no need for grep piping to awk

Comment: or even `awk '$4=="gone]"{print $1}'` to avoid matching the commit message

Comment: `git branch -D` accepts multiple branches, so no need for the loop. Also the format variable supports stripping parts. Hence this can be simplified to `git branch -D $(git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:strip=2) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads | awk '$2 == "[gone]" {print $1}')`

Answer (score 525):

Most of these answers do not actually answer the original question. I did a bunch of digging and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494276/3886183) was the cleanest solution I found. Here is a slightly more thorough version of that answer:

1. Check out your default branch. Usually `git checkout master`
2. Run `git fetch -p && git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

**Explanation:**

Works by pruning your tracking branches then deleting the local ones that show they are "gone" in `git branch -vv`.

**Notes:**

If your language is set to something other than English you will need to change `gone` to the appropriate word. Branches that are local only will not be touched. Branches that have been deleted on remote but were not merged will show a notification but not be deleted on local. If you want to delete those as well change `-d` to `-D`.

Comment: should add LANG=en_US  before git branch to force english : git fetch --prune && LANG=en_US git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d

Comment: I'd add `git checkout master && ...` at the beginning of the command.

Comment: This is dangerous when you're on a branch that's supposed to be deleted - in that case the first column is '\*', which is then passed to xargs. To improve this, add strip the '*' character before passing the output to awk:  sed -e 's/^\*//'

Comment: @MohamedELHABIB This doesn't work on my machine, and I think the better approach is to adjust the original command to your own language. Thanks for pointing it out though, I will update my answer.

Comment: @iarroyo Not everyone's default is `master` so that exact suggestion isn't safe, but yes, I forgot to mention it should be run from your default branch so I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: @meeee Right, but we don't want people to run this at all when they're on a branch that should be deleted. Running this from the default branch is the best solution because it addresses the root cause, I just forgot to mention it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @dlsso Why do we not want people to run it when they're on a branch that should be deleted? Git just warns about that and skips the branch. In this case, switching to another branch and re-running solves the problem. If you're making people _always_ switch to master, you make them do unnecessary work in case they're on a non-master branch that shouldn't be deleted. Also, I'd say the command filtering out the '*' is safer - it's easy to copy & paste and not think about what 'default branch' means.

Comment: @meeee Because it doesn't work. I want the instructions to be simple, and always work. To your other points, checking out a branch takes literally 2 seconds, and I think people who ignore the instructions would benefit from the learning experience.

Comment: @dlsso These instructions work for most people, but not for everyone (see comment above). Saying that people should learn from an accidentally deleted branch (that they might not easily know how to restore) is patronizing, when you can make the instructions more safe. You, yourself wrote above 'that exact suggestion isn't safe'. I still argue that safety is more important than always working. It's better for people to learn from 'not working' instead of learning from a deleted branch.

Comment: @meeee The instructions *do* work for everyone, and the rest is just a difference in philosophy. I chose to prioritize a working answer over safety for those who ignore instructions because I see stack overflow as a place to learn, not a place to publish a product. And I don't know about you, but I'd rather learn to follow instructions by deleting something that's a `git checkout` away than `rm -rf`ing a system directory. :)

Comment: To switch to a head branch first: `git remote show origin | grep "HEAD branch" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | xargs git checkout`

Comment: Careful! There is an edge case that will result in deleting all your local branches: If you are currently on a branch that was deleted on remote the output of `git branch -vv` will start with an asterisk which will in the end result in executing `git branch -d *`. Here is a patched version which will ignore lines with asterisk: `git branch -vv | grep ': gone]'|  grep -v "\*" | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs -r git branch -d`

Comment: @kcm That can only happen if you skip step 1.

Comment: @disso your default branch could be deleted on remote too. I wouldn't rely on that. As soon as an asterisk appears in the branch list, all your local branches will get deleted.

Comment: @kcm Not in any system I'm aware of. Github and Bitbucket certainly won't let you. The point of step 1 is to make sure no one tries to remove a branch they are on, and I still think it's foolproof. If you think you can make it clearer let me know, but I think "checkout default" is easier to read than "checkout a branch that you know is present on your remote."

Comment: I've been on projects where the default branch has changed. That would also trigger the situation @kcm is talking about.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Still only happens if you skip step 1.

Comment: You can set the default branch locally.  Safety is important and a what? 20 character change to your answer isn't going to change its clarity or usefulness.  Quite the opposite.   If this is a "difference of philosophy", remind me to check with my programmers about their "philosophy" before I hire them for a job :p

Comment: How can I stick this into an alias? I can't figure out how to escape all the ', $, etc.

Comment: @dlsso It says `error: The branch xx is not fully merged.`; but it did!
`

Answer (score 472):

I wouldn't normally answer a question that already has 16 answers, but all the other answers are wrong, and the right answer is so simple. The question says, "Is there a simple way to delete all tracking branches whose remote equivalent no longer exists?"

If "simple" means deleting them all in one go, not fragile, not dangerous, and without reliance on tools that not all readers will have, then the right answer is: no.

Some answers are simple, but they don't do what was asked. Others do what was asked, but are not simple: all rely on parsing Git output through text-manipulation commands or scripting languages, which may not be present on every system. On top of that, most of the suggestions use porcelain commands, whose output is not designed to be parsed by script ("porcelain" refers to the commands intended for human operation; scripts should use the lower-level "plumbing" commands).

Further reading:

- [why you shouldn't parse `git branch` output in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152574/587365).
- [tracking branches and the differences between `git remote prune`, `git prune`, `git fetch --prune`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107184/587365)

---

If you want to do this safely, for the use case in the question (garbage-collect tracking branches which have been deleted on the server but still exist as local branches) and with high-level Git commands only, you have to

1. `git fetch --prune` (or `git fetch -p`, which is an alias, or `git remote prune origin` which does the same thing without fetching, and is probably not what you want most of the time).
2. Note any remote branches that are reported as deleted. Or, to find them later on, `git branch -v` (any orphaned tracking branch will be marked "[gone]").
3. `git branch -d [branch_name]` on each orphaned tracking branch

(which is what some of the other answers propose).

If you want to script a solution, then `for-each-ref` is your starting point, as in [Mark Longair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7727380/587365) here and [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504680/587365), but I can't see a way to exploit it without writing a shell script loop, or using xargs or something.

---

### Background explanation

To understand what's happening, you need to appreciate that, in the situation of tracking branches, you have not one branch, but three. (And recall that "branch" means simply a pointer to a commit.)

Given a tracking branch `feature/X`, the remote repository (server) will have this branch and call it `feature/X`. Your local repository has a branch `remotes/origin/feature/X` which means, "This is what the remote told me its feature/X branch was, last time we talked," and finally, the local repository has a branch `feature/X` which points to your latest commit, and is configured to "track" `remotes/origin/feature/X`, meaning that you can pull and push to keep them aligned.

At some point, someone has deleted the `feature/X` on the remote. From that moment, you are left with your local `feature/X` (which you probably don't want any more, since work on feature X is presumably finished), and your `remotes/origin/feature/X` which is certainly useless because its only purpose was to remember the state of the server's branch.

And Git will let you automatically clean up the redundant `remotes/origin/feature/X` -- that's what `git fetch --prune` does -- but for some reason, it doesn't let you automatically delete your own `feature/X`... even though your `feature/X` still contains the orphaned tracking information, so it has the information to identify former tracking branches that have been fully merged. (After all, it can give *you* the information that lets you do the operation by hand yourself.)

Comment: This is a much safer answer. In addition, it will work if you use a "Squash and Merge" workflow, unlike the selected answer.

Comment: This really only answers the easy part of the question "how to find gone branches" (and that with the same command as already posted by jason.rickman in 2015) but then tells you to delete all the branches manually which is exactly what the OP doesn't want to do.

Comment: @Voo That's the point of the answer: not to tell you how to do it (that's just a bonus) but to tell you that the answer is that there is no easy, simple way to do it. Which is the correct answer to the question as it was formulated.

Comment: @Andrew It just seemed very unlikely that if you have a porcelain command that does exactly what you want, you couldn't use a plumbing command to get the same output reliably. I did ask a question about this and got [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503591/git-branch-status-via-plumbing-command?noredirect=1#comment93879166_53503591) in less than an hour. Probably should post an answer (#17?) along those lines.

Comment: @Voo Absolutely, and I did look at the plumbing commands, and found `for-each-ref`, but couldn't figure out a way to pass the output to a branch-deletion command without OS-specific tools like a looping script or xargs. Indeed I'm convinced the sense of the question was, "Does Git itself provide a [porcelain] command to do this in 1 line?" and it doesn't (though IMO it should).

Comment: @Voo p.s. updated answer to clarify the pb with porcelain, and link to your question.

Comment: I think you're wrong, there is a simple way, this answer :D

Comment: "If you want to do this safely, for the use case in the question.." - which negates most claims of the first paragraph. "[Git] can give you the information that lets you do the operation by hand yourself" - we're programmers, so given the information as a list (which is shown) the task is still simple (eg. `xargs`). There is also `git alias` to simplify a number of cases.

Comment: @user2864740 Some readers may consider that writing a small bash script falls within their definition of "simple", and that's a perfectly defensible position, but I gave my own interpretation of "simple" in the 2nd paragraph and the rest of the answer is consistent with it. And in defense of my admittedly restrictive interpretation, not all Git users have `xargs` or bash, and they probably aren't here looking for a micro-coding challenge, so much as a quick answer they can apply safely without distracting themselves further from their real goal.

Comment: I think using Git the answer to the question "is there a simple way to..." is pretty much always no.

Comment: there is no `git prune remote origin`, i assume you mean `git remote prune origin` instead?

Comment: I upvoted, but I disagree all other answers are wrong, "simple" should not be main factor in questions, and answers should give complicated solutions even if asked for a simple one (For future readers, who don't want just simple solution, but A solution). BUT i do agree they failed to mention there is no "simple" solution.

Comment: @athos thanks, fixed (first person to spot that in 4 years)

Comment: @Art3mix I admit it's provocative - when I added my answer, there were already 16 answers with significant reputation, and I felt like it needed justifying that I was adding anything at all

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once, very good explanations, although it feels a bit radical to say all other answers are wrong...

Answer (score 120):

#### Windows Solution

For Microsoft Windows Powershell:

`git checkout master; git remote update origin --prune; git branch -vv | Select-String -Pattern ": gone]" | % { $_.toString().Trim().Split(" ")[0]} | % {git branch -d $_}`

#### Explaination

`git checkout master` switches to the master branch

`git remote update origin --prune` prunes remote branches

`git branch -vv` gets a verbose output of all branches ([git reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--vv))

`Select-String -Pattern ": gone]"` gets only the records where they have been removed from remote.

`% { $_.toString().Trim().Split(" ")[0]}` get the branch name

`% {git branch -d $_}` deletes the branch

Comment: Thanks for this, though I had to add a `.Trim()` after `.toString()` in order to remove two spaces before the branch name.

Comment: Thanks for this command. I had to change the `git branch -d` to `git branch -D` else I get the error the branch is not fully merged.

Comment: @markieo You probably know this already, but for anyone else - `git branch -D` is **destructive** and will delete local work that you have not yet pushed. `-d` is always safe, just be careful with `-D`.

Comment: In case anyone wants to create an alias for this I was able to get it working through powershell with the following:

[alias]
    clean-local = "!powershell -Command 'git checkout master; git remote update origin --prune; git branch -vv | Select-String -Pattern \": gone]\" | % { $_.toString().Trim().Split(\" \")[0]} | % {git branch -d $_}'"

Answer (score 72):

I found the answer here:
[How can I delete all git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-are-already-merged)

```
git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

### Make sure we keep master

You can ensure that `master`, or any other branch for that matter, doesn't get removed by adding another `grep` after the first one. In that case you would go:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v "YOUR_BRANCH_TO_KEEP" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

So if we wanted to keep `master`, `develop` and `staging` for instance, we would go:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v "master" | grep -v "develop" | grep -v "staging" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

### Make this an alias

Since it's a bit long, you might want to add an alias to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`. Mine is called `gbpurge` (for `git branches purge`):

```
alias gbpurge='git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v "master" | grep -v "develop" | grep -v "staging" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d'
```

Then reload your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Useful, but not the same as "remove branches not on remote"

Comment: Greate answer @karlingen, I have this permanently as gbpurge across all my dev environments

Comment: How is this off-topic answer (a clunky one, at that) upvoted that much?

Comment: @RomainValeri That's a good question. This was answered 8 years ago. Don't remember why I posted this answer, but I sure was thinking the same way that all the upvoters were thinking when they read the question :)

Answer (score 69):

### TL;DR:

**Remove ALL local branches that are not on remote**

```
git fetch -p && git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D
```

**Remove ALL local branches that are not on remote AND that are fully merged AND that are not used** as said in many answers before.

```
git fetch -p && git branch --merged | grep -v '*' | grep -v 'master' | xargs git branch -d
```

### Explanation

- `git fetch -p` will prune all branches no longer existing on remote
- `git branch -vv` will print local branches and pruned branch will be tagged with `gone`
- `grep ': gone]'` selects only branch that are gone
- `awk '{print $1}'` filter the output to display only the name of the branches
- `xargs git branch -D` will loop over all lines (branches) and force remove this branch

Why `git branch -D` and not `git branch -d` else you will have for branches that are not fully merged.

```
error: The branch 'xxx' is not fully merged.
```

Comment: did you want to say remote instead of master?

Comment: Use Git Bash on window for above commands to work!

Answer (score 57):

You could do this:

```
git branch -vv | grep 'origin/.*: gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
```

P.S.:
as pointed out by [Sam H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3518108/sam-h)

execute this first:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Comment: don't you have to run `git remote prune origin` first?

Comment: Also pass `xargs git branch -D` (capital D) if you want to force a deletion

Answer (score 48):

The pattern matching for "gone" in most of the other solutions was a little scary for me.  To be safer, this uses the [`--format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---formatltformatgt) flag to pull out each branch's [upstream tracking status](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-upstream).

I needed a Windows-friendly version, so this deletes all branches that are listed as "gone" using Powershell:

```
git branch --list --format "%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" | 
    ? { $_ -ne "" } | 
    % { git branch -D $_ }
```

The first line lists the name of local branches whose upstream branch is "gone".  The next line removes blank lines (which are output for branches that aren't "gone"), then the branch name is passed to the command to delete the branch.

Comment: The `--format` option seems to be fairly new; I needed to upgrade git from 2.10.something to 2.16.3 to get it.  This is my modification for Linux-ish systems:
`git branch --list --format "%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname)%(end)" | sed 's,^refs/heads/,,' | grep . | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: This is the best solution so far. One suggestion is to use `refname:short`. Then you can delete the line `% { $_ -replace '^refs/heads/', '' }`

Comment: This is a great solution for windows. I am using it like this cause it is more readable `git branch --list --format "%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" | where { $_ -ne "" } | foreach { git branch -d $_ }` Also probably a good idea to use `-d` instead of `-D`. Force delete should not be necessary for branches that are no longer on remote.

Comment: While obvious to some of us, probably worth mentioning that you should be running "git remote update origin --prune" first.

Comment: slight improvement to this answer is to remove the empty responses in the format you can use ` --omit-empty`

Answer (score 47):

Yet another answer, because none of the solutions suit my needs on elegance and cross-platformness:

Command to delete local branches not on remote:

```sh
for b in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)' refs/heads); do git branch -d $b; done
```

To integrate it with gitconfig so it can be run with `git branch-prune`:

**Bash**

```sh
git config --global alias.branch-prune '!git fetch -p && for b in $(git for-each-ref --format='\''%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)'\'' refs/heads); do git branch -d $b; done'
```

**PowerShell**

```sh
git config --global alias.branch-prune '!git fetch -p && for b in $(git for-each-ref --format=''%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)'' refs/heads); do git branch -d $b; done'
```

(Need help in finding a universal command for PowerShell and bash)

### Why this answer is the best?

- Offers a complete solution: adds a `git branch-prune` command to your git
- Works fine from Windows PowerShell
- The core idea is [@jason.rickman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371037/jason-rickman)'s [bulletproof method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548037/3399377) using `git for-each-ref`
- Parsing and filtering is done with `--filter` so no external dependencies needed

### Explanation:

- Adds a new alias to your `~\.gitconfig`. After executing this you can simply do `git branch-prune`
- Inside this alias:

  - Fetches branches with the `--prune` flag, which "prunes remote-tracking branches no longer on remote"
  - Uses `git for-each-ref` and [`--filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-if), to get a list of the branches are [`[gone]`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2582083fa1830632e298727e973440907345267f/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L150-L151) (no remote)
  - Loops through this list and deletes the branch safely

Comment: [@jerry-wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8917446/jerry-wu) and your last edit of git config command does not work in PowerShell ((

Comment: Does this also remove local branches not yet pushed to remote? (a.k.a Work in Progress)

Comment: The short answer is NO.
If a branch is not merged, the `git branch -d branch-name` command used here will not remove it. It will send a notification that the branch is not merged, and show the command to delete it anyway (which is `git branch -D branch-name`)

Comment: For me this does report errors that the branch is not merged, even if the branch indeed is fully merged and was deleted from remote after the merge. error: The branch 'feature/...' is not fully merged. - Any suggestions?

Comment: check `git log --graph --all` ? Try `git branch -d feature/...` manually?

Comment: Thank you @Himura and @jerry-wu! As you are asking for a version of the command that works for both bash and posh, here it is:

`git config --global alias.branch-prune "!git fetch -p && for b in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)' refs/heads); do git branch -d $b; done"`

The outer double quotes should be safe (except _maybe_ in bash if the user has `$b` set as an ENV variable) and this actually matches the form that `git` itself use when storing the command text in `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: @DanielKing, no, it does not work in bash at all, sorry... For many reasons

Comment: Works in both WSL2 ubuntu 18.04 bash and MINGW ‍♀️

Answer (score 45):

```
git fetch -p
```

This will *prune* any branches that no longer exist on the remote.

Comment: this removes remote references, but not the local branches themselves.  While a useful command, I don't think this answers OP's question.

Comment: What? This deletes local branches for me.

Comment: @AlexHall The remote repository has a branch `X`; you `git checkout X`; now your repository has a (local) tracking branch `X` and a remote branch `origin/X`; the remote repository deletes `X`; you `git fetch-p`; in your local repository, not only `origin/X` but also `X` have been deleted. Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 41):

Remove all branches that have been merged into master, but don't try to remove master itself:

`git checkout master && git pull origin master && git fetch -p && git branch -d $(git branch --merged | grep master -v)`

or add an alias:

`alias gitcleanlocal="git checkout master && git pull origin master && git fetch -p && git branch -d $(git branch --merged | grep master -v)"`

Explanation:

`git checkout master`  checkout master branch

`git pull origin master`  ensure local branch has all remote changes merged

`git fetch -p` remove references to remote branches that have been deleted

`git branch -d $(git branch master --merged | grep master -v)`  delete all branches that have been merged into master, but don't try to remove master itself

Comment: One note, this is very helpful but it will also remove those branches that never have been pushed to the remote. It is safer to only list differences and then copy what you really want to delete into `git branch -D` command

Comment: Just to clarify, Zefiryn is referring to using the -D option which is not part of the one-liner.

Comment: Or juse the lowercase `git branch -d` which should issue a warning about not pushed branches.

Answer (score 30):

While the above answers cover how to prune branches manually, this answer adds automation to solve this. `git` now has a new setting to prune stale branches that are no longer on the remote for every fetch action. This is great because we no longer have to manually call `remote prune` every time we delete branches (`git pull` also calls `git fetch`).

### Enable prune behaviour for every fetch

To enable this in the global config:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

Making the thing happen automatically means you can forget to add this setting on new machines. It just works.

### Enable prune behaviour for every fetch on specific remotes

```
git config --global remote.<name>.prune true
```

### Local automated pruning

We can apply the same command for local pruning as well without the `--global` flag.

### .gitconfig

The commands above apply to the global and local `.gitconfig` as follows:

```
...
[fetch]
    prune = true
```

I can recommend adding this to an ansible configuration or to your dotfiles repository (`.gitconfig`) to automate the setup for the future.

The configuration setting calls the below command on every fetch:

```
git remote prune <remote name>
```

### Summary

To prune references as part of your normal workflow without needing to remember to run that, set `fetch.prune` globally or `remote.<name>.prune` per-remote in the config. See [git-config](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-fetchprune).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Executed the global setting (it's also in my .gitconfig), merged branch on github followed by `git fetch` + `git pull`. The branch still exists on my local.

Answer (score 20):

Yet-another-answer for the pile, drawing heavily from [Patrick's answer](/a/48411554) (which I like because it seems to do away with any ambiguity about where `gone]` will match in the `git branch` output) but adding a *nix bent.

In its simplest form:

```sh
git branch --list --format \
  "%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" \
  | xargs git branch -D
```

I have this wrapped up in a `git-gone` script on my path:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

action() {
  ${DELETE} && xargs git branch -D || cat
}

get_gone() {
  git branch --list --format \
    "%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)"
}

main() {
  DELETE=false
  while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case "${1}" in
      (-[dD] | --delete) DELETE=true ;;
    esac
    shift
  done
  get_gone | action
}

main "${@}"
```

NB - The `--format` option seems to be fairly new; I needed to upgrade git from 2.10.something to 2.16.3 to get it.

EDIT: tweaked to include suggestion about `refname:short` from **Benjamin W.**

NB2 - I've only tested in `bash`, hence the hashbang, but probably portable to `sh`.

Comment: Can't you skip the `sed` part by using `%(refname:short)` in the first line?

Comment: Seems to work for me, and I have it as a neat Git alias now – cleanest solution of all of them here!

Comment: 2.13 introduced `--format`. Another way to skip the `sed` part is to use `git update-ref -d`. Note that this is probably somewhat unsafe, using `git for-each-ref` is safer here (given `--shell`).

Comment: Great answer, and it's helped me answer my own questions when floundering with `--format` to do this myself.  Just one question: why the `#!bash`?  Everything here looks like portable `sh` to me.

Comment: That's just my normal boilerplate, and hadn't tested elsewhere.

Comment: Should probably use `xargs -r ...` so that `git branch -D` isn't run at all if there are no pruned branches

Comment: @rcoup yes that would be a worthwhile modification, if using GNU `xargs`.

Answer (score 18):

You can use this:

```bash
git fetch --prune
```

then

```bash
git branch -vv | egrep -v "([origin/[a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+])" | awk "{print $1}" | xargs git branch -D
```

It removes all the local branches that are not linked to the remote

and I personally added an alias that does it for me

```bash
alias gbs='git fetch --prune; git branch -vv | egrep -v "(\[origin\/[a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+\])" | awk "{print \$1}" | xargs git branch -D'
```

Comment: As this is the top answer, I went for this method first. I found this to be somewhat fragile as it depends on how git decides to format the branches. I've had some strange behaviour occurring, probably because I was running an older version of git on Ubuntu 18.04 and it formatted the git branches in a different way than what egrep was expecting. I would suggest using git for-each-ref instead to make sure that the branch formatting is consistent across all git versions.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think there is a built-in command to do this, but it is safe to do the following:

```sh
git checkout master
git branch -d bug-fix-a
```

When you use `-d`, git will refuse to delete the branch unless it is completely merged into `HEAD` or its upstream remote-tracking branch.  So, you could always loop over the output of `git for-each-ref` and try to delete each branch.  The problem with that approach is that I suspect that you probably don't want `bug-fix-d` to be deleted just because `origin/bug-fix-d` contains its history.  Instead, you could create a script something like the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

git checkout master &&
for r in $(git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname:short)')
do
  if [ x$(git merge-base master "$r") = x$(git rev-parse --verify "$r") ]
  then
    if [ "$r" != "master" ]
    then
      git branch -d "$r"
    fi
  fi
done
```

*Warning: I haven't tested this script - use only with care...*

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the script. Still won't give any guarantees, but, it runs and seems to work now.

Answer (score 16):

This will delete all the merged local branched except local master reference and the one currently being used:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v "*" | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -d
```

And this will delete all the branches having already been removed from the remote repository referenced by "*origin*", but are still locally available in "*remotes/origin*".

```
git remote prune origin
```

Comment: `git branch -vv | grep 'gone]' | grep -v "\*" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -r git branch -d`
**Explanation:** I prefer replacing the `git branch --merged` by `git branch -vv` to show the status (gone) because the previous `git branch --merged` can show also the master

Answer (score 15):

Might be useful to some, simple one line to clear all local branches except master and develop

```
git branch | grep -v "master" | grep -v "develop" | xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: Awesome answer! I like how one can easily play with the `'git branch | grep -v "master" | grep -v "develop"` kind of stuff before committing to adding on the deletion part of the command. 

Comment: But this does not answer the question above. This will delete branches even though remote is still there.

Answer (score 14):

Because some answers don’t prevent accidental deletion

`git fetch -p && LANG=c git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/&&!/^\*/{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

filtering out the branch having `*` in the first column is important.

Comment: Best solution for me. I added `LANG=c` so that it also works on non-english environments.

Comment: Why make it so complicated with the `-vv` and filter out the first column. Without the `-vv` you only get one column to start with.

Comment: because I am looking for `: gone]` – but you are right: a single `-v` would suffice.

Comment: `/^*/` won't work.  the * is meaningful and has to be escaped: `/^\*/`

Answer (score 13):

None of this was really right for me. I wanted something that would purge all local branches that were tracking a remote branch, on `origin`, where the remote branch has been deleted (`gone`). I did not want to delete local branches that were never set up to track a remote branch (i.e.: my local dev branches). Also I wanted a simple one-liner that just uses `git`, or other simple CLI tools, rather than writing custom scripts. I ended up using a bit of `grep` and `awk` to make this simple command.

This is ultimately what ended up in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  prune-branches = !git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -r git branch -D
```

Here is a `git config --global ...` command for easily adding this as `git prune-branches`:

```
git config --global alias.prune-branches '!git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | grep '"'"': gone]'"'"' | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"' | xargs -r git branch -d'
```

NOTE: In the config command, I use the `-d` option to `git branch` rather than `-D`, as I do in my actual config. I use `-D` because I don't want to hear Git complain about unmerged branches. You may want this functionality as well. If so, simply use `-D` instead of `-d` at the end of that config command.

Comment: I like the git alias approach. Quick question: Why doing `git branch -vv` and greping for `: gone]` and not do `git branch -v` and grep for `[gone]`?

Comment: @lalibi, good question. I don't remember. I suspect that something wasn't showing up with only one `v`. If `git branch -v | grep '[gone]'` works for you, go for it. It does seem a little cleaner.

Answer (score 12):

Powershell-based solution that I find more legible than many of the implementations here.

```bsh
# prune deleted remoted branches
git fetch -p

# get all branches and their corresponding remote status
# deleted remotes will be marked [gone]
git branch -v |
  #find ones marked [gone], capture branchName
  select-string -Pattern '^  (?<branchName>\S+)\s+\w+ \[gone\]' | 
  foreach-object{ 
     #delete the captured branchname.
     git branch -D $_.Matches[0].Groups['branchName']
  }
```

Comment: this script has 1 error, you need to add `.Value` at the end of `$_.Matches[0].Groups['branchName']`, so line will be `git branch -D $_.Matches[0].Groups['branchName'].Value`

Answer (score 11):

```
grep gone <(git branch -v) | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | xargs git branch -d
```

The above command can be used to fetch branches which are merged and deleted in remote and it deletes the local branch which no longer available in remote

Comment: Best solution so far, though I changed it to `grep gone <(git branch -v) | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | xargs git branch -D` to force delete all

Comment: Dangerous if any of your branch names happen to contain the substring `gone` anywhere in them (e.g. `usingonefunction`).

Comment: What if we grep [gone] instead of gone? wouldn't that avoid probable collisions? @TobySpeight

Comment: @dantebarba, I think so - as `grep -F '[gone]'` of course, to avoid the `[` being expanded by shell or used as a character class by grep.

Comment: dantebarba @TobySpeight agreed on the above points (y)

Answer (score 7):

Based on info above, this worked for me:

```
git br -d `git br -vv | grep ': gone] ' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs`
```

It removes all local branches with are `': gone] '` on remote.

Comment: It looks like this will also remove any branch that has "gone" in the last commit message.

Comment: It will also remove any branch that has `gone` anywhere in its name.

Comment: "git branch -D git branch -vv | grep ': gone] ' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs`"  This did the work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Drawing heavily from a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548037/478176) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411554/478176) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49518495/478176) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411554/2858703) here, I've ended up with the following (git 2.13 and above only, I believe), which should work on any UNIX-like shell:

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format='ref=%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname)%(end)' refs/heads | while read entry; do eval "$entry"; [ ! -z "$ref" ] && git update-ref -d "$ref" && echo "deleted $ref"; done
```

This notably uses `for-each-ref` instead of `branch` (as `branch` is a "porcelain" command designed for human-readable output, not machine-processing) and uses its `--shell` argument to get properly escaped output (this allows us to not worry about any character in the ref name).

Comment: It works for me, but it would also be nice if you could explain what the other steps in the command are doing. For example I don't know what `[ ! -z "$ref" ]` means. I think a multi liner would have helped already. But still thanks for your input!

Comment: @KevinH I guess it means when $ref is not empty

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution for Windows or others who don't want to/can't script the command line or who don't want to bother with PowerShell.

Dump the branch list into a file
`git branch > branches.txt`
(or `git branch --merged > branches.txt`, if you're the belt and suspenders type;
`git branch -d` will protect against deleting unmerged branches)

Open that file in your editor and combine all the lines (I used sublime text, so highlight all and press `ctrl+j`)

Add `git branch -d`  ahead of your branch list.

Select all, copy, and paste (right click in windows cmd window) into the command line.

Comment: Easy, safe, cross OS, full management, understandable.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Git Tip: Deleting Old Local Branches](http://erikaybar.name/git-deleting-old-local-branches/), which looks similar to [jason.rickman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548037/3827) I implemented a custom command for this purpose called [git gone](http://eed3si9n.com/git-gone-cleaning-stale-local-branches) using Bash:

```
$ git gone
usage: git gone [-pndD] [<branch>=origin]
OPTIONS
  -p  prune remote branch
  -n  dry run: list the gone branches
  -d  delete the gone branches
  -D  delete the gone branches forcefully

EXAMPLES
git gone -pn    prune and dry run
git gone -d     delete the gone branches
```

`git gone -pn` combines the pruning and listing the "gone" branches:

```
$ git gone -pn
  bport/fix-server-broadcast         b472d5d2b [origin/bport/fix-server-broadcast: gone] Bump modules
  fport/rangepos                     45c857d15 [origin/fport/rangepos: gone] Bump modules
```

Then you can pull the trigger using `git gone -d` or `git gone -D`.

#### Notes

- The regular expression I used is `"$BRANCH/.*: gone]"` where `$BRANCH` would normally be `origin`. This probably won't work if your Git output is localized to French etc.
- Sebastian Wiesner also ported it to Rust for Windows users. That one is also called [git gone](https://swsnr.de/blog/2018/09/23/git-gone/).

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer - `git gone` looks like an alias for `git branch -vv | grep 'origin/.*: gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`, which solves the OP's issue.

Comment: imo would be better if it used `for-each-ref`

Answer (score 4):

I like using pipes because it makes the command easier to read.

This is my solution if you would like to remove all branches except master.

```
git branch | grep -v master | xargs -n 1 git branch -D
```

To delete other branches that match your criteria, modify the first and second block.

```
git branch --merged | grep feature_name | xargs -n 1 git branch -D
```

Comment: Can be simplified a bit: `git branch --merged | grep -vE 'main|master|\\*' | xargs -n 1 git branch -D"`

Answer (score 4):

May be this command is what you want.

After run:

```
git remote prune origin
```

then run:

```
diff <(git branch | sed -e 's/*/ /g') <(git branch -r | sed -e 's/origin\///g') | grep '^<'
```

this will show all branch which not in (git branch -r) but in (git branch)

*This method have a problem, it will also show the branch in local which have not pushed before*

Comment: It worked on terminal but how can I put it in git alias?
I am using like `show_deleted = "diff <(git branch | sed -e 's/*/ /g') <(git branch -r | sed -e 's/origin\///g') | grep '^<'"` but it throwing error.

Answer (score 3):

List all local branches who's remote branch is now gone

```bash
#!/bin/sh
LC_ALL=C git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads/ |\
    sed -n '/ *\[gone\].*$/{s@@@;p}'
```

and then pipe that into `xargs git branch -D` or `-d`.

This solution should be POSIX compatible. No shell specific stuff and POSIX compliant `sed`/`xargs` only.

- `LC_ALL=C` makes the script language neutral by forcing english
- `for-each-ref` use plumbing command
- `--format='%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)` output *branch name* *tracking information*
- `refs/heads` only local branches
- `sed -n '/ *\[gone\].*$/` match the tracking information  `[gone]` which is not part of a valid branch name so no need to worry about that

  - `{s@@@;p}` delete that tracking part and only print those lines

**nb**: branches cannot contain whitespace so we don't need to do any sanitation for `xargs`.

Answer (score 3):

We need more answers on this one, so here's my variation:

What I was missing was a way to make this less magical and more day-to-day friendly, so I've combined some of the other answers and ended up creating 2 aliases:

1. `gonelist` that lists all the branches that have a remote which is now gone
2. `gonedelete` that deletes those same branches `gonelist` returns.

You can add them to your global git config like this:

```
git config --global alias.gonelist '!git for-each-ref --format "%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)" refs/heads | grep -F " [gone]" | cut -d" " -f1'
git config --global alias.gonedelete '!tmp="$(mktemp)" && git gonelist >$tmp && vi $tmp && < $tmp xargs git branch -d'
```

### the workflow

1. `git fetch --prune` Git tells you that some branches where deleted remotely.
2. `git gonelist` List if your local branches to see if any have missing remotes.
3. `git gonedelete` And editor opens and and you can remove all listed branches except for the ones you wish to delete. Then save and close the editor (`:wq`) and those branches will be deleted. (You might need to switch branches first if you wish to delete the current branch.)

###### Explanation gonelist

- `git for-each-ref --format "%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)"` - Lists all branch heads with optional '[gone]' suffix.
- `grep -F " [gone]" | cut -d" " -f1` - Gets only the `[gone]` branches and then removes the `[gone]` part.

###### Explanation gonedelete

- `tmp="$(mktemp)" && git gonelist >$tmp` - create a tmp file and write the output of `gonelist` to it.
- `vi $tmp` - Edit the file with `vi`
- `< $tmp xargs git branch -d` - feed the contents of the `tmp` file to `git branch -d`.

`gonedelete` gives you a prompt to edit the branches that should be deleted using `vi` (but you can replace that with any other editor if you like), and then deletes those branches. If you get an `error: The branch '...' is not fully merged.` message, you can just add `-D` to the command and it will force-delete the branches you picked.

Answer (score 2):

The real challenge is when the maintainer squashes the commits. Then, the solutions using git built-in functionality such as `--merged` does not help.

The tool [git-delete-merged-branches](https://pypi.org/project/git-delete-merged-branches/) allows for a convenient deletion of branches. I especially like the interactive mode.

Installation (requires `python3`):

```
pip install git-delete-merged-branches
```

Then execute

```
git-delete-merged-branches --effort=3
```

`--effort=3` is important to enable deletion of squashed branches.

### Alternatives

- [@teppeis/git-delete-squashed](https://github.com/teppeis/git-delete-squashed#teppeisgit-delete-squashed-forked): With node.js installed execute `npx @teppeis/git-delete-squashed`. Supports `main` branch.
- [git-delete-squashed](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/git-delete-squashed): Not maintained: Misses functionality for `main` branch. @teppeis/git-delete-squashed is based on this.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all local references where the previously remote tracking branch is now gone

```
#!/bin/sh
LC_ALL=C git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads/ |\
    sed -n '/ \[gone\]$/{s@@@;p}' |\
    xargs -I% git branch --delete %
```

1. `LC_ALL=C`, avoid problems with localization by setting language to English
2. Match `for-each-ref` output ending with  `[gone]` and take the refname
3. Prune those local references (change `--delete` to `-D` to force)

No bashisms and should work in BSD/GNU

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this bash script. It always keep the branches `develop`, `qa`, `master`.

```
git-clear() {
  git pull -a > /dev/null

  local branches=$(git branch --merged | grep -v 'develop' | grep -v 'master' | grep -v 'qa' | sed 's/^\s*//')
  branches=(${branches//;/ })

  if [ -z $branches ]; then
    echo 'No branches to delete...'
    return;
  fi

  echo $branches

  echo 'Do you want to delete these merged branches? (y/n)'
  read yn
  case $yn in
      [^Yy]* ) return;;
  esac

  echo 'Deleting...'

  git remote prune origin
  echo $branches | xargs git branch -d
  git branch -vv
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a short method to do the trick, I recommend you to do the same as it could save some hours & give you more visibility

Just add the following snippet into your .bashrc (.bashprofile on macos).

```
git-cleaner() { git fetch --all --prune && git branch --merged | grep -v -E "\bmaster|preprod|dmz\b" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d ;};
```

> 1. Fetch all remotes
> 2. Get only merged branches from git
> 3. Remove from this list the "protected / important" branches
> 4. Remove the rest (e.g, clean and merged branches)

You'll have to edit the grep regex in order to fit to your needs (here, it prevent master, preprod and dmz from deletion)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
```

Comment: oh, i double posted this on... just saw this when reviewing posts. But you really could point to the guy who provided this command instead of taking this as yours!

Comment: I get it from a forum don’t try to be smart just take the answer or ignore it

Comment: Even than you could... anyway... didnt came here to discuss this with you. As you sayed.. .take my comment or ignore it ;)

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here seemed to work for me or do exactly as I wanted (delete local branches not in remote). So I wrote this, it's a bit of a mouthful but it works.

```
touch /tmp/remote-refs && touch /tmp/local-refs && touch /tmp/diff-refs;
while shortened=$(git for-each-ref refs/remotes) && echo ${${shortened}//"\/remotes\/origin"} > /tmp/remote-refs &&
shortened=$(git for-each-ref refs/heads | grep -v "master\|develop") && echo ${${shortened}//"\/heads"} > /tmp/local-refs &&
diff=$(comm -13 /tmp/remote-refs /tmp/local-refs) && echo ${${diff}##*refs/} > /tmp/diff-refs &&
xargs git branch -D </tmp/diff-refs; do :; done
```

Just have to make sure to run `git remote prune origin` first

Comment: The following command seems to be the key. How does it work?
`$(comm -13 /tmp/remote-refs /tmp/local-refs)`

Comment: unix compare command which gets everything inside local-refs that's not in remote-refs. Therefore all you're left with are branches in local that are not in remote.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
git remote prune origin
git branch -d bug-fix-a bug-fix-b
```

The risk of using scripts to do this is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47939403/4592031

Comment: If you like to see what git will do *before* you impact the repo, use: `git remote prune --dry-run origin` This will output what git *would* do, so you can verify that it matches your expectation.  Sample Output: `* [would prune] origin/your-branch-name` - *would* being the key word here.  If you like what you see, then you can run the command without the `--dry-run` option.  The output then changes to: `* [pruned] origin/your-branch-name`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet Another Answer.

If you are looking for something fancy, here is the alias I use with [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

```bash
LANG=C git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format '%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads \
  | awk '$2 == "[gone]" {print $1}' \
  | fzf --multi --bind ctrl-a:select-all,ctrl-t:toggle-all \
        --preview='git log --color=always --graph --format=compact {1}' \
        --header='Select [gone] branch to remove' \
        --header-first --reverse \
  | xargs --no-run-if-empty git branch -d
```

[image: output example]

### Explanations:

- Force `LANG=C` to avoid localization on `[gone]` pattern
- Use `git for-each-ref` to be free from any format changes in `git branch`
- Filter using `awk`. I tried to use `--format="%(if:equals=[gone])%..."` but it implies to manage blank lines.
- Use `fzf` to select the branches to delete.

  Adds shortcuts: `[ctrl-a]` to select all, and `[ctrl-t]` to invert the selection (and `[tab]` to select as usual). You validate using `[enter]` and can abort using `[esc]`. I use this branch selector as a confirmation stage.
- Display the selected branch's log on the right side (to remember the date and content...).

  I use a `compact` format listed below. You can use any (not too wide) log format.
- `--no-run-if-empty` is only available with GNU `xargs`.

  It is not mandatory and helps to avoid errors when you abort the process (related to `git branch -d` without branch names).

The alias may look awful:

```
[alias]
      gone = "!f() { LANG=C git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format '%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads | awk '$2 == \"[gone]\" {print $1}' | fzf --multi --bind ctrl-a:select-all,ctrl-t:toggle-all --preview='git log --color=always --graph --format=compact {1}' --header='Select [gone] branch to remove' --header-first --reverse | xargs --no-run-if-empty git branch -d ; }; f"
[pretty]
      compact = %Cred%h%Creset%C(auto)%d%Creset%n  Author: %an <%aE>%n  Date:  %cd%n     %s
```

(same as above with escapes on `"`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for how long, but I do use git-up now, which takes care of that.

I do `git up` and it starts to track new branches and deletes the old ones.

Just to make it clear, it is not out-of-box git command — https://github.com/aanand/git-up

BTW it also stashes dirty tree and makes rebases still with just `git up`.

Hope it'll be useful for someone

Comment: This isn't deleting local branches that don't exist on the server.

Comment: The tool is not maintained any more. - The maintainer recommends `git config --global alias.up 'pull --rebase --autostash'` as replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I use for the fish shell. Tested on `Mac OS X 10.11.5`, `fish 2.3.0` and `git 2.8.3`.

```
function git_clean_branches
  set base_branch develop

  # work from our base branch
  git checkout $base_branch

  # remove local tracking branches where the remote branch is gone
  git fetch -p

  # find all local branches that have been merged into the base branch
  # and delete any without a corresponding remote branch
  set local
  for f in (git branch --merged $base_branch | grep -v "\(master\|$base_branch\|\*\)" | awk '/\s*\w*\s*/ {print $1}')
    set local $local $f
  end

  set remote
  for f in (git branch -r | xargs basename)
    set remote $remote $f
  end

  for f in $local
    echo $remote | grep --quiet "\s$f\s"
    if [ $status -gt 0 ]
      git branch -d $f
    end
  end
end
```

A few notes:

Make sure to set the correct `base_branch`.  In this case I use `develop` as the base branch, but it could be anything.

This part is very important: `grep -v "\(master\|$base_branch\|\*\)"`.  It ensures that you don't delete master or your base branch.

I use `git branch -d <branch>` as an extra precaution, so as to not delete any branch that has not been fully merged with upstream or current HEAD.

An easy way to test is to replace `git branch -d $f` with `echo "will delete $f"`.

I suppose I should also add: USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Python script using [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to do delete local branches which don't exist on remote.

```py
    import git
    import subprocess
    from git.exc import GitCommandError
    import os

    def delete_merged_branches():
        current_dir = input("Enter repository directory:")
        repo = git.Repo(current_dir)
        git_command = git.Git(current_dir)

        # fetch the remote with prune, this will delete the remote references in local.
        for remote in repo.remotes:
            remote.fetch(prune=True)
        
        local_branches = [branch.name for branch in repo.branches]
        deleted_branches = []

        # deleted_branches are the branches which are deleted on remote but exists on local.
        for branch in local_branches:
            try:
                remote_name = 'origin/'+ branch
                repo.git.checkout(remote_name)
            except GitCommandError:
            # if the remote reference is not present, it means the branch is deleted on remote.
                deleted_branches.append(branch)
            
        for branch in deleted_branches:
            print("Deleting branch:"+branch)
            git_command.execute(["git", "branch", "-D",branch])

    
        # clean up the work flow.
        repo.git.checkout('master')
        repo.git.pull()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        delete_merged_branches()
```

Hope someone finds it useful, please add comments if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple answer that worked for me using a git client:

Delete the repository altogether from your machine then check out again.

No mucking around with risky scripts.

Comment: What about the branches I am currently working on :/

Comment: @MailoSvětel if they are on your remote then you can just pull them again (remember to commit and push your latest work to your remote!)

Comment: In my question and in most of the answers, we're trying to avoid unnecessary work. In other words: What I need to do is just remove the branches, I'll not work on anymore. Removing repo, cloning it and start tracking the branches again, is a lot of unnecessary work for me. Besides that, some work could get lost :(

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this is a very pragmatic approach

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `zsh` shell with `Oh My Zsh` installed then the easiest way to do this safely is to use the built in autocomplete.

First determine which branches you want to delete with:

```
~ git branch --merged

  branch1
  branch2
  branch3
* master
```

this will show you a list of already merged branches

After you know a few you want to delete then type:

```
~ git branch -d
```

All you have to do is hit [tab] and it will show you a list of local branches. Use tab-complete or just hit [tab] again and you can cycle through them to select a branch with [enter].

Tab Select the branches over and over again until you have a list of branches you wnat to delete:

```
~ git branch -d branch1 branch2 branch3
```

Now just press enter to delete your collection of branches.

If you aren't using zsh on your terminal... [Get it here.](https://ohmyz.sh/)

Comment: This works for local branches, but doesn't really answer "tracking branches not on remote", which was OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted a solution which I've been using for quite some time, which relies on branch naming to include issue numbers, you can [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68117517/3625433) which links to my version of [git_clean_branches](https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/730577210d08c2d9d38778b6f088d281) which is an interactive script to delete branches who's issues have been closed (normally by a squash merge).

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally you simply want to have a clean slate, but need to be certain to be able to go back to previous work in a local branch.

If so, the easiest might simply be archiving the current local clone and create a new fresh one.

So for repository X just with the default branch locally, simply

```
move X X-2021-11-10
git clone http://...../X
```

If you need the exact same origin, ask git

```
git -C X remote -v
```

Comment: It's good to have backups in general, but there's no need to do this: fetching the latest branches from a remote, or resetting your current branch, neither affects any other local branches.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everyone has a solution. Well, if you prefer an interactive tool with TUI (text-based user interface), I wrote a tool called git xcleaner. It can find merged branches, rebased branches (commits with the same commit message), pruned branches or manually selected branches.

https://github.com/lzap/git-xcleaner

Answer (score 0):

I made this script condensing all the knowledge that I found in all the answers:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bclean()
{
  if [ "$1" == "--interactive" ] || [ "$1" == "-i" ]; then
    true > /tmp/merged-branches

    # Append gone
    git fetch -p && \
    for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads | awk '$2 == "[gone]" {sub("refs/heads/", "", $1); print $1}'); do
       echo "${branch}" >> /tmp/merged-branches
    done

    # Append without remote
    IFS=$'\n'
    git fetch -p && \
    for line in $(git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) %(upstream)' refs/heads); do
      # If the second field is empty, it has no upstream
      if [ -z "$(echo "${line}" | cut -d " " -f2)" ]; then
        # Detect name and append it
        branch="$(echo "${line}" | cut -d " " -f1 | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev)"
        if ! grep -q "${branch}" < /tmp/merged-branches; then
          echo "${branch}" >> /tmp/merged-branches
        fi
      fi
    done

    # Append merged
    current="$(git branch --show-current)"
    for line in $(git branch --merged | sed '/^\** *develop$/d' | sed '/^\** *master$/d' | sed "/^\** *${current}/d" ); do
      if ! grep -q "${branch}" < /tmp/merged-branches; then
        echo "${branch}" >> /tmp/merged-branches
      fi
    done

    if grep -q '[^[:space:]]' < "/tmp/merged-branches"; then
      nano "/tmp/merged-branches"
      xargs git branch -D < /tmp/merged-branches
    fi
    unset current

  else
    # Delete gone
    git fetch -p && \
    for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads | awk '$2 == "[gone]" {sub("refs/heads/", "", $1); print $1}'); do
      git branch -D "${branch}"
    done

    # Delete without remote
    IFS=$'\n'
    git fetch -p && \
    for line in $(git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) %(upstream)' refs/heads); do

      # If the second field is empty, it has no upstream
      if [ -z "$(echo "${line}" | cut -d " " -f2)" ]; then
        # Detect name and delete it
        git branch -D "$(echo "${line}" | cut -d " " -f1 | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev)"
      fi
    done

    # delete merged
    current="$(git branch --show-current)"
    git branch --merged \
    | sed '/^\** *develop$/d' \
    | sed '/^\** *master$/d' \
    | sed "/^\** *${current}/d" >/tmp/merged-branches \
    && grep -q '[^[:space:]]' < "/tmp/merged-branches" \
    && xargs git branch -d </tmp/merged-branches
    unset current

  fi
}

alias git-branch-clean="bclean"
```

#### Explanation

This script deletes all branches that do not have a remote counterpart. It does not matter that is gone, merged, not pushed yet or whatever. It just deletes all local branches that are not on the server anymore. It also ignores the branches `master` and `develop`.

The function works in two different modes: interactive and non-interactive.

If you use `bclean --interactive` or `bclean -i` all the branches are appended to a temporary file and then you have the option to decide which branch you want to actually delete.

Instead, if you use `bclean` without arguments all branches that do not have a remote counterpart are deleted without further interaction.

This is tested and working in Ubuntu 20.04.2 and git 2.25.1.

This script is version managed in a bigger project and any mistakes, corrections or updates will be available through [this repository](https://github.com/AleixMT/Linux-Auto-Customizer). Specifically in [this file](https://github.com/AleixMT/Linux-Auto-Customizer/blob/develop/data/features/bclean/bclean.sh).

#### How to use

If you want to add this script *manually* to your system you can add this text directly to your `.bashrc` to make the function `bclean` always available in your terminal.

If you want to add this script *automatically* to your system you can use the Linux-Auto-Customizer project where this script is included as a single installation. To do so, you have to type these instructions in your terminal:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/AleixMT/Linux-Auto-Customizer
cd Linux-Auto-Customizer
git checkout develop  # Not needed when we do next release
bash src/core/install.sh -v -o bclean
bash  # To reload .bashrc and make the function available in the current terminal. Equivalent to source ~/.bashrc
```

After that, the function `bclean` can be used in a terminal.

Answer (score -4):

> This Below Commands Solved My problem.

```
// To Delete Branch Locally
git branch -d localBranchName


// To Delete Branch Remotely
git push origin --delete remoteBranchName
```

Answer (score -5):

This is gonna delete all the remote branches that are not present locally (in ruby):

```
bs = `git branch`.split; bs2 = `git branch -r | grep origin`.split.reject { |b| bs.include?(b.split('/')[1..-1].join('/')) }; bs2.each { |b| puts `git  push origin --delete #{b.split('/')[1..-1].join('/')}` }
```

Explained:

```
# local branches
bs = `git branch`.split
# remote branches
bs2 = `git branch -r | grep origin`.split
# reject the branches that are present locally (removes origin/ in front)
bs2.reject! { |b| bs.include?(b.split('/')[1..-1].join('/')) }
# deletes the branches (removes origin/ in front)
bs2.each { |b| puts `git  push origin --delete #{b.split('/')[1..-1].join('/')}` }
```

Comment: this does actually the opposite of what the question asked.

Answer (score -6):

I use this method so I can have more control.

`git branch -D $(git branch | grep -v "master" | grep -v "develop")`

This is remove any branches not named: `master` or `develop`.