# How can I clean up my local branches if they are deleted from GIT repo

Tags: git, github

How can I delete all my local branches if they are deleted from GIT repo. Is there any command for that ? . I dont want to it one by one by the command git branch -D/-d branch-name .

Comment: you mean local branches or remote tracking branches on you machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: My question is different from this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cleaning up old remote git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches)

Comment: This is just reverse I am asking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove branches not on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590160/remove-branches-not-on-remote)

Answer (score 16):

**Remove information on branches that were deleted on origin**

When branches get deleted on `origin`, your local repository won't take notice of that.

You'll still have your locally cached versions of those branches (which is actually good) but git `branch -a` will still list them as remote branches.

You can clean up that information locally like this:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Your local copies of deleted branches are not removed by this.

The same effect is achieved by using

```
git fetch --prune
```

You could also set that as a default.

Answer (score 7):

Just for reference if someone looking in this page later

Quiet good amount of details on the same

[DevConnect Page](https://devconnected.com/how-to-clean-up-git-branches/)

Command which we can use for fully merged local branches is

```
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|main|dev)" | xargs git branch -d
```

This will list merged branches, grep for lines that are not `master`, `main`, or `dev`, then delete each of these branches.

Answer (score 5):

To delete (or "prune") local branches that are not in the repo

```
git remote prune origin
```

> **prune**
>
> Deletes all stale tracking branches under <name>. These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by <name>, but are still locally available in "remotes/<name>".
>
> With --dry-run option, report what branches will be pruned, but do no actually prune them.

Comment: Local copies of deleted branches are not removed by this.

Comment: yes, i was looking for this. `git remote prune --dry-run origin` was it for me. there was `origin/branch` in remote which got deleted (say, after a merge request), but the local (well, the local on codespace) was still showing it; this fixed it (:

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are asking for a way to delete your own branch named `train` if there was an `origin/train` at one point and there is no longer an `origin/train` now.

This is (a) somewhat dangerous and (b) difficult to do (because there is nothing built in to remember that "there was an `origin/train`"), but if you redefine the problem a bit, it's much less difficult.  It remains dangerous.  It means you are telling your software to *automatically destroy information* whether or not that loses information you did not want destroyed.  For instance, you may have put a lot of work in the last day or two into your `train` and then someone deletes the upstream `origin/train` not realizing that you are working on it.  Now you tell your Git to delete your `train` without ever giving you a chance to *restore* `origin/train`, and you lose the work you just did.

(You can get your work back, through the `HEAD` reflog, but it's not a very good plan—which is why I call this "somewhat dangerous".)

To see ways to delete branches that have lost their upstreams (e.g., after running `git remote prune origin` or `git fetch --prune origin`), see [Remove local branches no longer on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7726949/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

If you need/want to do it in Powershell, you can use this

```
git branch --merged | ForEach-Object { git branch -d ($_).Trim() }
```

It will delete all the branches merged with the currently checked out branch.
The current branch will not be deleted.