# GIT: remove remote branches with no local tracking branch

Tags: git, branch, remote-branch

Let's say that `git branch -a` outputs something like this:

- A
- B
- C
- *master
- remotes/origin/A
- remotes/origin/B
- remotes/origin/C
- remotes/origin/master
- **remotes/origin/X**
- **remotes/origin/Y**
- **remotes/origin/Z**

In bold are those branches (X, Y, Z) that are in the remote repository but I have not checked them out yet and I don't even intend to, they are related to a project I don't participate in.

Is there a command to remove all remote branches (**those that are saved on MY repository, not the actual remote branch in the remote**) which do not have a local tracking branch?

**Edit**: I intend to remove remote branches that are saved in my repository, showing the existence of the branch in the remote. I do not want to remove the actual branches in the remote.

**Edit 2**: Clarification in comment to mattmilten

You can recreate all remote branches with `git pull`, but I don't always `git pull`.

I often just `git fetch origin master A B C` and then merge or rebase or do anything I want with branches master, A, B or C.

Point is, whenever I "git pull" (for some reason), all the branches I don't want are created and it seems I have no simple option to remove them afterwards.

Comment: With `git push origin :Y` can you delete a remote branch

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The information about (all) branches is a part of your repo and will always be copied when a new clone is created. You need to ignore these branches or simply run `git branch` to list only your local branches.

How would you be able to retrieve remote branches at a later time, if you delete the information about their existence?

Comment: When you "git pull", you get all these remote branches recreated. But I don't always "git pull", I just "git fetch origin master A B C" and then merge or rebase what I want in A or B or C.

Edit: point is, whenever I "git pull" (for some reason), all the branches I don't want are created and it seems I have no simple option to just avoid them completely.

Comment: Point is, remote branches are not really "created" on your local repository. Think of them as virtual branches. It sounds like you don't like the output of a `git pull` printing all these remote branches you don't need - `git pull -q` might be a solution...

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem but in a different situation. I deleted a local branch *experiment1*. I forgot to `git branch --unset-upstream` first, so I still had a remote tracking branch. Branch *experiment1* was deleted from the remote after.

Later, when I ran `git branch -a`, it keep showing up in output as `remotes/origin/experiment1`. Neither `git branch --unset-upstream` nor `git branch --delete` would get rid of it because the local branch was already gone. Referencing it as *origin/experiment1* instead of *experiment1* did not work either.

So this is what I did:

1. `cd .git/refs/remotes/origin`
2. `rm experiment1`

And it no longer shows up in output and normal Git sync commands worked as expected after.

I am adding this answer because this is the top hit in an Internet search for "git remove remote-tracking branches with no local branch". Also, this question is different enough from ["Remove tracking branches no longer on remote" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-tracking-branches-no-longer-on-remote) to **not** be a duplicate. If I were to wrote my own question that this answer answers, then that question would be a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Finally a solution that doesn't involve the actual remote!