# Git command to sync remote branch with local branches

Tags: git

Is there a command to sync the remote and local branches?

For example, I have deleted few branches from remote which are no longer useful using command `git remote update --prune`. Now I have these deleted branches locally.

Is there a command to delete the local branch if there exists no remote copy of same branch?

Comment: ACtually the command you fired should have worked.

Comment: Check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-branches-no-longer-on-remote) if any of them suits your specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch --prune` should do what you are looking for.

Comment: That didn't helped mate. I still have local branches which were deleted from remote.

Comment: Sorry I'm late to the party. I just had to do the same thing as OP and through I'd share. I deleted branch `my-feature` from the remote after merging the associated PR. This left 2 `my-feature`-related refs in my local repo: local branch `my-feature` as well as `origin/my-feature`. `git fetch --prune` is used to remove `origin/my-feature` while `git branch -d my-feature` is used to delete the local branch. Hope this helps any fellow archaeologists!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in command in Git for this task.  You have to write a script in your favorite language.  I'll use Powershell but you can always transform it to some fancy *SH one-liner.

#### Test rig

Script: [gist.github.com/tkirill/7c14331de4da814069af](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/7c14331de4da814069af).  It does:

1. [Creates](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/7c14331de4da814069af#file-git-test-rig-ps1-L15) a repo `test-repo` with two branches: branch1 and branch2.
2. [Clones](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/7c14331de4da814069af#file-git-test-rig-ps1-L39) the repo to `test-clone`, and goes to this clone and checkouts all branches.  The last step effectively creates corresponding local branches.
3. [Removes](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/7c14331de4da814069af#file-git-test-rig-ps1-L52) branches `branch1` and `branch2` on origin.
4. [Leaves](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/7c14331de4da814069af#file-git-test-rig-ps1-L80) you in `test-clone`.

#### Removing branches

Script: [gist.github.com/tkirill/0f0f1902beb0c0723582](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/0f0f1902beb0c0723582).  It does:

1. [Gets](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/0f0f1902beb0c0723582#file-remove-local-branches-ps1-L17) local branches.
2. [Gets](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/0f0f1902beb0c0723582#file-remove-local-branches-ps1-L42) remote branches [without](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/0f0f1902beb0c0723582#file-remove-local-branches-ps1-L33) remote name.
3. [Removes](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/0f0f1902beb0c0723582#file-remove-local-branches-ps1-L53) every local branch that [not exists](https://gist.github.com/tkirill/0f0f1902beb0c0723582#file-remove-local-branches-ps1-L65) on remote.

#### Running experiment

```
.\test-rig.ps1
..\remove-local-branches.ps1
```

Output of the last command shows us that both `branch1` and `branch2` were deleted:

```
Removing branch branch1
Deleted branch branch1 (was ab1575a).
Removing branch branch2
Deleted branch branch2 (was c9a24c2).
```

#### But that's not the end

Writing such script can be pretty tricky if you want a universal solution.  For example, the script takes branches from all remotes, not only origin.  You may want to work with origin only.

But the main problem from my point of view is that it can remove local branches which not merged in develop.

#### Remove merged branches only

I think this is really what you need.  Merged branches have little use.  There are a lot of scripts and aliases doing this task since, it is really common.  [Choose](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=remove+merged+git+branches) what you like the most :)  As for Windows I [wrote](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/pull/159) corresponding extension for posh-git.