# How do I delete already merged local Git branches with TortoiseGit?

Tags: branch, tortoisegit

I would like to find solution for problem very well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-local-branches-no-longer-on-remote) - in short, this problem can be solved with `git branch -d $(git branch --merged)` when commandline used - question is, is there possibility to do the same in TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 2.3 TortoiseGit only helps you for automatically cleaning up remote tracking branches.

You can do this automatically when you use the Pull/Fetch-dialog an check "Prune". Then all remote-tracking references which are not there on the remote are automatically removed.  On Sync dialog select "Clean up stale remote branches" in the pull/fetch menu button.

Starting with version 2.3.2 you can open the Browse References dialog and filter for merged/unmerged branches. Using that filter you, then, can delete unneeded branches/tags.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was not the question, question was how to automatically get rid of not used local branches. As i get, its not possible in tortoiseGit, right ?

Comment: Updated: Right, with the current stable version it is not possible. I just updated the answer. The new preview release will be available at the latest by the end of this week. See https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/commit/5ae17723583c8cd616940a417207a3976cb91c2b

Comment: Its worth noting that Browse References is in the extended options by default, so you have to [shift]+rightClick on the folder to get it

Comment: Be aware you'll also need a sufficiently high level of Git, not just TortoiseGit. I had 1.9 and the relevant Browse References filter was grayed out. I was surprised at this, since I'd only installed Git in 2015 and I had assumed my TortoiseGit updates would have updated that also. It does not.