# git fetch -p -f not pruning local branches with GitHub

Tags: git, github

OK, there are a lot of answers around this topic, and perhaps I have an environmental problem, but wanted to see if there is some secret GIT sauce I am missing.

I am having problems getting my local repo in sync with GitHub.  When I run `git branch -a` I get this list:

```
Gideon
Qs
SK-tabfix
dev
list
master
new-metrics
sk-notifications
* sk-utf-fix
remotes/origin/GG-dev
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/KH-dev
remotes/origin/dev
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/sk-utcoverage
remotes/origin/sk-utf-fix
```

- I've run `git fetch -p -f` - no change.
- I've run `git remote prune origin` - no change.
- I've run `git pull --prune` - no change.

Obviously I can manually delete the local branches, but I cannot understand why prune is failing me here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove tracking branches no longer on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-tracking-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

Answer (score 1):

Local branches are not meant to be affected by any of the commands your are showing.

`git remote prune` only prunes remote-tracking branches, not local ones.

Similarly, `git fetch -p` or `git pull --prune` will only affect remote-tracking branches. The remote-tracking branches are the ones named `remotes/origin/...`.

The local branches whose upstream is a remote-tracking branch are still local and must be deleted with `git branch -d` or `git branch -D`.

Comment: Hmm.  The interesting thing is all those branches did exist on remote and some were actually merged.  So I'd expect that history to be reflected during a fetch.  For instance: ```git fetch --prune
From https://github.com/redargyle/csvuploader
 - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/SK-tabfix
 - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/sk-notifications```