# How can I list all remote existing branches in Git?

Tags: git

I have tried `git remote -r` to view all remote existing branches, but I found the result includes those branches that are deleted remotely.

Is there a way to filter out these "zombie" branches?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove tracking branches no longer on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-tracking-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

Comment: `git fetch --prune`

Comment: Please check the [ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) documentation.

Answer (score 37):

This question has several possible underlying meanings, so it has several possible answers.  The key issue here is that there are at least *two different* Git repositories involved.

#### Remotes

Before we get to the two answers, let's mention that a *remote* is just a short name like `origin`.  The remote itself holds the *URL* by which your Git calls up some other Git.  You can have as many remotes as you like.  There are additional things you can do with a remote, besides just storing a URL, but storing a URL is sort of the main thing.  The `git remote` command is the main user-facing command for working with remotes, but since `git clone` *creates* the remote named `origin` for you initially, you almost never actually need to use `git remote`.

#### Remote-tracking names

Your Git, on your computer, keeps and updates *your* Git repository.  Your Git has *your* branch names, tag names, and other names, and a collection of commits.  The *commits* are the part that your Git shares with other Git repositories, though there is some degree of name-sharing as well.

Meanwhile, because you Git has called up another Git before, and remembers the URL *for* that other Git under the name `origin`, your Git *also* remembers *their* Git's branch names.  To do this, your Git creates, in your repository, *remote-tracking names*<sup>1</sup> such as `origin/master`.  These names simply remember that, the last time your Git called up the other Git at `origin`, *they* said that *their* `master` was some particular hash ID.

When you run `git fetch origin` (or just `git fetch`, if there's only one remote named `origin`), your Git calls up the other Git at that point, obtains any new commits that they have that you don't, and updates all your remote-tracking `origin/*` names.

Running `git branch -r` will list your remote-tracking names, so `git branch -r` shows you what your Git saw in their Git, the last time your Git updated using their Git.  Note that `git branch -a` includes `git branch -r`, but adds the word `remotes/` in front of the `origin/master` names.<sup>2</sup>

One problem that occurs here, though, is that they can *delete* some branch name(s).  Suppose, for instance, that their Git *had* a branch named `feature/tall` yesterday, but no longer has that branch.  Your Git called up their Git yesterday, and created or updated your `origin/feature/tall` to match their `feature/tall`.  Now your Git calls up their Git and they *don't* list a `feature/tall`.

- By default, your Git does nothing about this.
- If you run `git fetch --prune`, however, your Git calls up their Git as usual, lists out all their branch names, and discovers that you have a *stale* `origin/feature/tall`, made back when they had `feature/tall`, and *removes* it.

So in general, you should add `--prune` to each `git fetch`, so that your Git's remote-tracking names are deleted as soon as your Git notices that they are stale (but not before then).  You can *configure* your Git to do this automatically:

```
git config fetch.prune true
```

You can configure your Git to have this as its default for *all* your repositories, on your laptop or whatever machine you use, with:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for a (very long) list of everything `git config` can actually do.

---

<sup>1</sup>The Git documentation mostly calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but I think the meaning is eventually clearer if we leave the word *branch* out of here.

<sup>2</sup>All of Git's names—branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and other such names—live in [*namespaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) and have longer, fully-qualified names to make them explicit.  For instance, your `master` branch is really `refs/heads/master`; your tag `v1.2`, if you have one, is really `refs/tags/v1.2`.  Remote-tracking names like `origin/master` are really `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

Git normally strips off the `refs/heads/` part of branch names, the `refs/tags/` part of tag names, and the `refs/remotes/` part of remote-tracking names, when showing you these abbreviated names.  For some reason, `git branch -a` only strips off the `refs/` part when showing remote-tracking names, even though `git branch -r` strips off the `refs/remotes/` part.  (The reason for this is not clear to me.)

---

#### Branch names on the remote

Because there is a second Git involved here, you could also just have your Git call it up *right now*, have it list out all its branch names, and have your Git print those names.  The `git ls-remote` command does exactly this:

```
git ls-remote origin
```

calls up the Git at `origin`, has them list out their branch and tag and other such names, and then prints all of them.  (It *does not* update any of your remote-tracking names: that's left to `git fetch`, and also to `git remote update`.)

The `git remote show` command *can* also call up the other Git and get information directly from it, and show that.  Sometimes it does and sometimes it does not.  This *is* documented, though not terribly clearly; see [the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for details.

## Summary

- `git branch -r` shows your Git's remote-tracking names.  This is quick as it is entirely local.  But it may be out of date.
- `git fetch` updates your Git's remote-tracking names; add `-p` or `--prune` to make it clean out stale ones, or set `fetch.prune` to true.  This is slow since it also adds any new commits they have that you don't, but afterward, your remote-tracking names are quick to use.
- `git remote update` basically does the same thing as `git fetch`.  Since `git fetch` is shorter to type in, I recommend using `git fetch` instead.
- `git ls-remote` calls up another Git and gets its branch names.  This is somewhat slow, but not as slow as `git fetch` if there are new commits, as it does not obtain the commits—only the names and corresponding hash IDs.
- `git remote show` sometimes works locally, and sometimes calls up the other Git.  I find its behavior somewhat confusing and not very helpful, and generally recommend avoiding it.

Answer (score 12):

#### To list branches:

```
# -a = all branches
$ git branch -a

# -r = remote branches
$ git branch -r
```

---

## To remove branches

#### `git fetch`

`git fetch` will update your local repository with the content form the remote.

Adding `--prune` will **remove** deleted branch from the remote **but** will not delete them locally if they are checked out

```
$ git fetch --all --prune
```

---

#### `git remote prune`

In order to clean up remote-tracking branches, meaning deleting references to non-existing remote branches, use the “git remote prune” command and specify the remote name.

```
$ git remote prune <remote name>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you list remote references with `--heads` parameter specified, you will get the branches.

`git ls-remote --heads`