# Github Desktop - Branch Not Deleting

Tags: github, github-for-mac, github-desktop

I deleted a branch on Github after merging my changes, however the branch still appears in Github Desktop.

The below are the steps I took:

1. Made some changes to my local .sql file.
2. Commit the changes using Github Desktop.
3. Push the changes to the Origin.
4. After merging the changes in Github I deleted the branch.

The branch is no longer in Github but it is still available from the branch drop down menu in Github Desktop.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Perform a fetch origin, or a pull.

Answer (score 2):

Since [July 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-07-02-github-desktop-branch-pruning/), GitHub Desktop should propose a pruning option, which allows to  removes unused branches from your local repository after they’ve been merged and deleted on GitHub.com to help keep your branch list relevant and uncluttered.

That solves [issue 750](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/750) with [PR 6544](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/pull/6544)

> This PR adds a feature that will auto-prune branches based on these conditions:
>
> - The branch is deleted on GitHub.com and
> - merged locally into the default branch in Desktop and
> - has no commits ahead of the default branch

If the local branch is not pruned automatically... you [need to go to the command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464339/6309):

```
git fetch
git remote prune origin
```