# Git branch merged list local branches with zero commits as merged

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm developing a simple script to show local branches (their status, etc) and I'd like to know which of my branches have been already merged to the master branch. Normally I have several branches (corresponding to fixes/features, etc). Some of them have an associated PR that at some point get merged to the remote origin. So I'd like to know which ones have been merged (so I can delete them locally for i.e). The problem is that when I have new/fresh branches (with 0 commits on them) the following git command lists them as merged which is confusing:

```
git branch --merged master
```

In the following example (took from a candidate answer):

```
          K--L   <-- br1
         /    \
...--F--G--H---M   <-- master, br3
      \
       I--J   <-- br2
```

I would like to show **br1** as merged, but not **br3** (**br2** is not merged in this case obviously). Please, keep in mind that master is evolving all the time so the above diagram is not realistic, normally **master** will move quickly and **br3** becomes behind master so **br1**. The difference between **br1** and **br3** is that **br1** at some point *diverged* (due to commits) and then it was **merged** again to master. However, **br3** is just pointing to a rev on master but has never had (so far) any different commits.

Comment: This is because the new branch created from master is identical to master.

Comment: You said, "I'd like to know which of my branches have been already merged to the master branch." Like you said, any new branches with 0 new commits fall into that category, but you *don't* want them listed. So, this raises the question, "What do you *really* want to know?"

Comment: Consider this, you create a branch `feature1` off of `master`. You add some commits, and merge it into `master` (let's assume it fast forwards). Now you create branch `feature2` off of `master`. At this moment `feature1`, `feature2`, and `master` are all identical. Yet, it sounds like you want to run a command that returns `feature1`, but not `feature2`, is that correct?

Comment: You can compare the history of `master` and the branch (say its name is `feature1`), If identical, then it's a new branch or a branch that's merged 'fast forwardly'. Otherwise it's a merged branch, but must check as well the last `master` commit's parents. `feature1` should be one of them. Anyway, as @TTT said, it might be helpful if you mention why do you need it exactly.

Comment: @TTT yeah, you assumption is correct. I only want to mark as "merged" branches that had some work that has been already merged. Normally I have several branches with fixes and some new branches that I create to work on. So I only wan to mark as merged the first ones.

Comment: @rkachach ok. From Git's POV there isn't a difference, but maybe we can come up with something. Still though, *why* do you want to see that list? Are you trying to determine which branches you can delete?

Comment: @TTT yeah, exactly. Once a branch is merged I can go and delete it locally.

Answer (score 1):

No branch, in Git, ever has no commits on it.  This is because a branch name is an entity holding the hash ID of a valid existing commit.  That valid existing commit is a commit, so the branch has at least one commit on it:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, br1, br2
```

Here the names `master`, `br1`, and `br2` all select commit `H`.  The set of commits that is on each branch is exactly the same as the set of commits that is on the other two branches.

People often *say* that "`br1` has no commits" when what they *mean* is "`br1` has no commits that are not also on `master`".  What you can do is count the number of commits that are *different* between any two branch names:

```
          K--L   <-- br1
         /    \
...--F--G--H---M   <-- master, br3
      \
       I--J   <-- br2
```

Here, the result of:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right master...br3
```

will be `0 0` because the two branches are even with each other, while the result of:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right br1...master
```

will be `0 1` because `br1` is strictly behind `master` (has no commits that `master` lacks) but `master` is strictly ahead of `br1` (has commit `M`, which `br1` lacks).  The result of:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right br2...master
```

will be `2 5`, because `br2` has two commits (`I-J`) that are not reachable from `M`, while `master` has five commits (`G-H-M` and `K-L-M` but Git avoids double-counting `M`) that are not reachable from `J`.  (Commits `F` and earlier are reachable from both and are therefore not counted.)

Note that this syntax requires the three dots between the two names, and the `--left-right` option to split out the two counts.  You can also use `git branch --merged master` to quickly eliminate `br2` as a candidate: the result of `git branch --merged master` will be the list of names that are behind or even with `master`.  Having found that list, you can then eliminate any name that is even with `master`:

```
if [ $(git rev-parse $branch) = $(git rev-parse master) ]; then
    # branch is even with `master` so
    # `git rev-list --left-right --count` would
    # produce 0 0
else
   # branch is behind `master`
fi
```

Note: do not use `git branch` in a script; use `git for-each-ref` instead.  (Use `git branch` if and only if you have a sufficiently ancient Git that `git for-each-ref` lacks the `--merged` option.  However, if you have a Git that old, you should consider upgrading it.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and for dedicating time to answer my question. I updated the same with more details. I hope my purpose is clear after the updates since the first version I didn't include all the details about what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Having read your update, I think what you need to do is: (1) read the output of `git branch --merged` or equivalent, using your own eyeballs and brain; (2) filter this down to the list of "branches I intend to keep using" vs the list of "branches I don't intend to keep using"; (3) delete entries from the second list. The key here is the intent to keep using it: that's not something any software can understand.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** Since your goal is to know which local branches you are done working on and can be deleted, the command you tried isn't sufficient. You'll need to do something else first, or use a different method entirely.

**Explanation:**

I think the source of your question really comes from the wording used by the `branch` option `--merged`, which is confusing since "merged" means something slightly different in Git than it does in English.

The [documentation for `--merged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) states (emphasis mine):

> With --merged, only branches merged into the named commit (**i.e. the branches whose tip commits are reachable from the named commit**) will be listed.

For example, after you merge `my-branch` into `master`, `my-branch` is going to appear as "merged" when you run the command `git branch --merged master`, but it doesn't appear in the list because you *merged* it in, it appears because after you merged it in the branch is now *reachable* from `master`. Any new branch you create from `master` without adding new commits is of course also reachable, and consequently will also be considered "merged" by Git. Note, after merging `my-branch` into `master`, if you add a new commit to `my-branch`, it will no longer appear as "merged" from Git's POV even though you previously did "merge" it. The point here is whether or not you actually ran `git merge` somewhere to merge a branch in, isn't necessarily relevant to whether or not Git considers the branch "reachable".

**Possible Alternatives:**

**Simple:** There is a very simple solution that would enable you to keep doing what you're doing. Any time you create a new branch, add an empty commit to it, perhaps with some comment that may be useful. For example:

```
git fetch
# make your branch...

# Add an empty commit:
git commit --allow-empty -m "wip: Improve performance by refactoring"
```

By adding a blank commit it will no longer be reachable from `master`. When you're ready to work on that branch just amend (and remove the "wip: " prefix in the subject), or reset back a commit before you make your first commit on that branch.

**Better?** If you use a SCM tool to merge your branches into `master` rather than doing it locally, and if your workflow is to delete your remote branches after they are merged in (which really ought to be the default and most tools offer this as a selectable option when completing a PR), then you can (and probably should) prune your remote tracking branches, and then you can identify which local branches *used* to have a remote tracking branch but no longer do. [Here's an example of this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548037/184546)

**Simplest?** What if you just delete all "merged" branches, and use some other mechanism to determine what you have to work on (e.g. issue tracker or project management tool). Having a bunch of branch names sitting there with no new commits on them isn't necessarily helping you, other than to remind you that you need to do it.

**Creative with a Caveat:** Of all the solutions, I think this one is probably what you are envisioning in your head, but it has a pretty specific caveat in that it will only work if every one of your feature branch merges uses `--no-ff` and creates a merge commit. So, **if** you always use `--no-ff` (or if `master` moves so quickly that you'll always need a merge commit **and** you don't rebase your feature branch), then you should be able to filter the branches by those who's tip commit is reachable by `master`, and also if a merge commit exists on `master` with that tip commit as one of it's parents. This might take a *minute* to script out but once you have it, you can re-use it indefinitely.