# Update everything in remote git repository from origin

Tags: git, version-control

I have created a simple git repository that contain just `programe.txt` file. After that I created a remote repository in `remote` folder, so the project is now looks like this:

```
D:.
├───local
│       programe.txt
│
└───remote
    └───local
            programe.txt
```

Then I created `user2` branch from remote repository and I added `programe2.txt` file to this branch.
To push all changes, I entered these commands:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin user2
```

I merged `user2` into `master` from origin repo. Everything just worked fine until I deleted user2 branch when I was in origin repo; because in remote repo I have `user2` branch, but it does not exist in origin repo:

```
D:\Git\local>git branch -a
* master
```

```
D:\Git\remote\local>git branch -a
* master
  user2
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

How can I update everything (like branch state) from origin repo?

I have tried these command but none of them worked:

```
git pull origin
git pull --rebase
git remote update origin [--prune]
git fetch [--all]
git push origin --delete user2
git reset [--hard]
```

Comment: `in remote repo I have user2 branch, but it does not exist in remote repo`  something not clear here. Can you do `git fetch` in both directory ?

Comment: Have you taken a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-tracking-branches-no-longer-on-remote

Comment: I mean I have `user2` branch which exist in cloned repo, but it is deleted from origin. How can I update branches state from origin when I am in cloned repo? @Ôrel

Comment: Each repository is *independent*. It exists on its own, and has *its own* branches. Humans use branch names and assign significance to them, but Git doesn't really care. You don't have to use the same names in two different repositories. We *do* use the same names, though, because we are humans and not computers. But just because you delete a name in *one* repository does not mean it is gone from others. They're *independent*. If you want to delete the name from all the clones, you must issue one delete request per clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because in remote repo I have user2 branch, but it does not exist in origin repo:

Then a simple git fetch would restore the remote tracking branch origin/user2 that you deleted. See [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47696235/6309).

> How can I update branches state from origin when I am in cloned repo?

If your goal is to *also* delete the `user2` branch on the origin repository, you would need to push its deletion: `git push --delete origin user2`