# cannot see updates in Git remote repository

Tags: git

I have created a remote git repository on a remote server in this place: `/home/mysite/public_html/git/mysite.git` and set `/home/mysite/public_html` as a remote working directory specified.

On my local machine I successfully cloned the repository with `git clone http://user@mysite.com/git/mysite.git` and pushed a test file in it:

```
git add test.txt
git commit -am "test update"
git push origin master
```

The operation shows no errors - it seems to be updating local repository, however, I cannot find any files in the remote repository and neither in the working directory.

Another thing - if I delete my local repository and clone it again from the server, the text file comes along, meaning it is stored somewhere in the remote repository, just not where I need it. What could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: add output of `git log`

Comment: Local log shows commits, remote shows error: `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

Comment: you should synch your local and remote branch

Comment: this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373277/git-sync-local-repo-with-remote-one

Answer (score 1):

You might have created you remote repository with this command :

```
git init --bare
```

If that is the case, this repo is not an ordinary repo, as you can't work in it. But it will work perfectly as a remote repo, and you can clone, pull, fetch etc...

If you didn't use the `--bare` option, your remote repo work as all other repos, you have to do a pull to get your updates :

```
git pull
```