# Sync local git repo with remote in one shot discarding local changes/commits

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a not a git expert so this might look like a silly question.

I have local and remote repositories, I want to sync my local with the remote repository. I have many local changes, stashed changes, and few commits which are not yet pushed to remote.

One way can be to remove all local changes(using `git clean`), revert commits and than `fetch/pull` from remote. But I think there must be some single command which can do all this in one go. I tried using `git reset --hard HEAD` and then `git pull` but that gave me:

```
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 9 different commits each, respectively.
```

Was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373277/git-sync-local-repo-with-remote-one) as well, but didn't help.

Comment: You could use the steps in FractalSpace's answer over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373277/git-sync-local-repo-with-remote-one and put them in a script

Comment: If you want to set your master branch to the same as the remote master branch, you could try "git reset --hard origin/master"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As commented, a `git reset --hard origin/master` would reset your `master` to upstream.

But: your current master (with its local commit) would be "lost" (at least, no longer visible).

So *one* step isn't the best approach.

I would recommend something like:

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git branch tmp
git reset --hard origin/master
git checkout tmp
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

That way, you rebase your local commit(s) on top of the updated master

```
x--x--x--x--x (master, origin/master)       x--x--x--x--x--y'--y' (tmp, master)
       \                                 =>
        y--y  (tmp)                           (after rebase+merge)
```

Answer (score 4):

This command will discard all local commits on a branch and reset it to mirror what is currently on the remote:

```
git pull
git reset --hard origin/your-branch
```

The pull command is to make sure what you have is the most up to date of the branch

Answer (score 0):

The permanent fix if you always want to create a new branch on the remote to mirror and track your local branch(or vice-versa) is:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

I always configure my local git with this command after I do git clone. Although it can be applied anytime when the local-remote branch **"Git fatal: The current branch has no upstream branch"** error occurs.

Hope this helps. Much peace. :)

Answer (score -6):

```
git fetch -[options]
```

To learn more about the `fetch` command run `git fetch --help`

Comment: Your comment is of no real help