# git fetch origin --prune doesn't delete local branches?

Tags: git, git-fetch

At one point I thought that `git fetch origin --prune` deleted local branches that were no longer present on the server. Somehow this is not my experience at the moment.

I ran this command, and the local branch was not deleted. It is *not* currently checked out. I ran `git branch -vv` to check this info, and I see

```
feature/MyGreatFeature           f30efc7 [origin/feature/MyGreatFeature: gone]
```

So it seems to know that it is gone. Why would it not delete my local branch?

Running `git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove tracking branches no longer on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-tracking-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim yes the script on that answer achieves this, similar to the answer below

Comment: Sorry for the automatically created unintentional question - the comment should be  [“Possible duplicate”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/the-auto-comment-does-this-answer-your-question-generated-when-voting-to-clos)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The various prune options (`git remote update --prune`, `git remote prune`, `git fetch --prune`) *only* delete remote-tracking branches.<sup>1</sup>

You'll need to manually delete local branches you no longer want, or change or remove their upstream setting if the remote-tracking branch no longer exists.  Note that each local branch can record a remote and/or branch that do not now, or even never did, exist.  In this case Git mostly acts as if those local branches have no upstream set, except that since version 1.8.5, several commands report the upstream as "gone" or otherwise invalid, and may suggest using `--unset-upstream`.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, they delete destination refs after doing the refspec mapping from the command line or `fetch` lines from the configuration.  Hence, for fetch mirrors, they *can* delete local branches.  Most clones are not set up as fetch mirrors, though.

There were some recent bug fixes for complex mappings, to make sure that Git did not prune a mapped branch in some cases when it should not.  For any normal repository—ordinary clone or pure fetch mirror—these fixes have no effect; they matter only if you have complicated `fetch` configurations.

Comment: if there is a branch listed in the `[]` on `git branch -vv` isn't it a remote-tracking branch in that case?

Comment: Not necessarily: the thing in `[...]` is simply the upstream.  If the upstream is a remote-tracking branch, that's when it's likely to get pruned.  In your example, you have `[origin/feature/MyGreatFeature: gone]` which looks like a remote-tracking branch that has already been pruned.  Git still has local branch `feature/MyGreatFeature`, and in `.git/config`, that branch still has its remote set to `origin` and its upstream set.  You can, e.g., delete the local branch (which deletes its tracking info), or `--unset-upstream` on it if you want to keep the local branch with no upstream set.

Answer (score 100):

The following command chain can be used to delete local branches:

```sh
git branch --v | grep "\[gone\]" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D
```

- `git branch --v` lists the local branches verbosely
- `grep "\[gone\]"` finds all the branches whose remote branch is gone
- `awk '{print $1}'` outputs only the name of the matching local branches
- `xargs git branch -D` deletes all the matching local branches

This should work on MacOS as well as *nix environments.

Comment: this is a great solution, but now git defaults to using system language and [gone] might be a different string

Comment: This works perfect in MacOS and *nix. If someone is looking for similar functionality of windows, below commands will be useful:  1) git branch --v | find "[gone]" > tmpBranches.txt   2) for /f "tokens=1" %a in (tmpBranches.txt) do git branch -D %a  3) del tmpBranches.txt

Comment: After trying so many solutions on other threads this is what finally worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice. I turned this into a git alias: ```purge = !git branch --v | grep '\\[gone\\]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D```

Answer (score 21):

This is how I do it with Powershell.

```
PS> git branch --v | ? { $_ -match "\[gone\]" } | % { -split $_ | select -First 1 } | % { git branch -D $_ }
```

You can then create an alias like:

```
PS> Function func_gitprune { git branch --v | ? { $_ -match "\[gone\]" } | % { -split $_ | select -First 1 } | % { git branch -D $_ } }

PS> Set-Alias -Name gitprune -Value func_gitprune
```

and execute it every time you need by running

```
PS> gitprune
```

Comment: Would this benefit from running a `git fetch` beforehand so you're in sync? something like `& git fetch --prune; & git branch --v | ? { $_ -match "\[gone\]" } | % { -split $_ | select -First 1 } | % { git branch -D $_ }`

Comment: I came up with very similar:  `git branch --v | ? {$_.contains('[gone]')} | % {$_.trim().split()[0].trim()} | % {git branch -D $_}`

Answer (score 9):

The command you want is

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-local-branches-no-longer-on-remote) is almost word for word what you're looking for.

Comment: For more git branching/merging madness, [check this question out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064613/how-to-prune-local-tracking-branches-that-do-not-exist-on-remote-anymore).

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean? It's failing with an error? Does the command succeed but it's not having the desired effect?

Comment: right it "succeeds" (there is no output) and nothing happens, the branches still have the "gone" tag

Comment: @jonathan: `git remote prune origin` only deletes your remote-tracking branch (e.g. `remotes/origin/mybranch`). It does not delete your local branch (e.g. `mybranch`). You have to delete those separately.

Answer (score 3):

For me this line works:

```sh
git branch -vv | grep "gone" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: this is exactly shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228595/571778 but has less explanation

Comment: There is a bit diffrent 1. -vv VS --v 2. grep "gone" VS grep "\[gone\]"

Comment: what if you name your branch `gone`

Comment: I understand the problem, But when I use "[gone]" it doesnt work for me, only "gone"

Comment: @yano then your branch will be `gone`

Comment: You appear to have not read the previous answers which covered this a long time before . https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228595/37370

Answer (score 1):

In case you need the Windows Command Line version:

```
git fetch --all --prune
git branch --all --verbose | for /F "tokens=1" %i in ('findstr /c:"[gone]"') do git branch -D %i
```

Comment: The second command doesn't work for me in Windows. I get the error `"[gone]"') was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Maybe you can just remove the double quotes @SkyWalker

Answer (score 0):

In case people need the PowerShell version:

```sh
git branch --v | Select-String -Pattern ".*\[gone\].*" | ForEach-Object{($_ -split "\s+")[1]} | ForEach-Object{git branch -D $_}
```