# Pruning branches in Visual Studio 17 git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am very new to git and I gave GitHub integration in Visual Studio 2017. Everything is going well so far but whenever I do a pull request and merge branches I will delete the unused branch after the merge is complete on the web client. This works well but in Visual Studio, the branch I have deleted does not go away. I've seen other questions about this and the most common answer is to run the command `git config remote.origin.prune true` so when a fetch or pull is performed the repository will automatically prune the appropriate branches.

While I have no doubt that this will work I just don't know where to be running this. I've already tried running that in the windows CMD under the repository path (after right-clicking the repository in Visual Studio and selecting "open in Command Prompt") and it didn't throw any errors but also didn't seem to do anything at all after I ran through creating and merging another branch.

UPDATE:
After looking into it a bit more I've realised the REMOTE/ORIGIN branch is being deleted but not the local one.

[image: TestEdits does not exist on GitHub anymore]

Is there a way to delete the branch locally automatically to match the remote?

Comment: _"the branch I have deleted does not go away"_ - locally, or on origin? You'll have to explicitly delete it on origin.

Comment: So upon further testing, the branch will be deleted on the remote but not locally. I'm using the GitHub website to perform all my merges and deletes of branches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned here, the prune option would only remove (on fetch) "remote tracking branches" (ie, branches defined in the `refs/remotes` namespace).
Meaning that branches deleted on the server side would also be deleted locally only for `refs/remotes` branches.

The [local branches would still remain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664434/6309).
You [still have to remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16906759/6309), using command-line:

```
git branch --merged master | grep -v '^[ *]*master$' | xargs git branch -d
```

Comment: Well, thats slightly annoying but I guess I'll just have to live with it. I can also remove the local branches by just right clicking on them in VS and selecting delete which isn't too bad but I was hoping for a more automated solution!

Comment: @NickHallick I agree, this is not very convenient. Maybe there is a possibility to define a custom command/shortcut in Visual Studio itself.