# 'git branch -a' still showing deleted remote branch in the remote repo?

Tags: git

I have uploaded (pushed the entire local branch) to the remote repo.
I have merged it with master and deleted it in the remote repo (on github.com)

Running `git branch -a` still shows it in the console:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/hivauz/master
  remotes/hivauz/new_local_branch
```

What's the reason, does github need time to update it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git remote branch deleted but still appears in 'branch -a'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094293/git-remote-branch-deleted-but-still-appears-in-branch-a)

Comment: Additionally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664226/git-fetch-origin-prune-doesnt-delete-local-branches/37664362

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 14):

You have to run `git fetch --all --prune` in order to remove the remote branch reference in your local environment.

Comment: hmm it's stil lthere.. strange

Comment: Let me correct myself, just in case: `git fetch --all --prune`.

Comment: it's stil lthere