# how to synch existing local repo with bitbucket repo?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I had to change my laptop hdd to sdd, I have backup of my local files. Now I want to synch my local files and existing bitbucket repo without losing my changes in my local folder.

What is the correct way to do it  ?

Thanks

edit : tried to solve same way as the suggested question before suggestion, I got errors
 `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

I had to do following steps 
first  `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`

then 
`git merge origin origin/master`
after commit and git push origin master

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: sync local repo with remote one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373277/git-sync-local-repo-with-remote-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps to push changes without loosing any code

1. Clone latest to some new folder
2. Create a branch from master/develop so that master/develop branch is not disturbed. Let's say branch  name jinnabalu/existing-sync
3. Copy the files or folder to the repo cloned
4. Check with the difference.

   > git status
5. Push your changes to your remote branch (jinnabalu/existing-sync)

> git add --all
>
> git commit -am "Sync local folder"
>
> git push -u origin jinnabalu/existing-sync

6. Merge your branch (jinnabalu/existing-sync) to master or develop from where you have created

> git checkout master
>
> git pull
>
> git checkout jinnabalu/existing-sync
>
> git merge --no-ff origin master
>
> git checkout master
>
> git merge --no-ff origin jinnabalu/existing-sync