# How to fix "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit."?

Tags: git, github

I have a local checkout of a repository of a fork on my computer (from github). So on github I created a fork, and checked that out.

Now I want the local checkout to be the same as the original github repository (the one I created the fork from). I added that original repo to my local repo (with the name 'orig') and did the following:

```
git pull orig master
```

However, `git status` shows me

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Also `git diff` or `git diff origin/master` shows nothing.

Is there a way to make the local checkout equal to what is in the original master branch (without removing the local repo, the github fork, forking anew, checking out anew...)?

I do not care if there any uncommited changes or anything. I want the local checkout to be equal to the original repo...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: sync local repo with remote one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373277/git-sync-local-repo-with-remote-one)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can reset your local branch to the one in orig, then push to your fork

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git push --force origin master
```

Your local repo and fork master branch will be the same as the original repo.

If need clean: `git clean -f -d`

Comment: Do i need to save my local changes before executing above commands ?

Comment: @DeepakYadav Yes: at minimum a `git stash`, or even a `git add` + `git commit` is advisable. After a `reset --hard`, you will still able to get your changes back by cherry-picking that commit from the reflog, or by pop stashing https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt.

Answer (score 3):

Use the command below :

`git reset --hard HEAD`

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue a couple of times now and the below is the solution I wrote down for myself. I don't know all the details but I know it got me out of trouble :).

Rolling back on Commits. (run "git status" between each step)

- e.g. "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 2 commits."

1. git reset HEAD^:

- This removes one committed file at a time (I think)
- There will be a bunch of (red) staged/untracked files. Don't panic.

2. "Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged, and have 1 and 5 different commits each, respectively."

- Repeat step 1. until git status "Your branch is behind 'origin/dev' by 5 commits"
- Now we want to remove all those changes so we can later pull origin back in.

3. git restore *

- Removes all the staged changes
- Now there may just be some Untracked files. Manually go delete them in the folder.

4. git pull origin dev.

- This should be the latest dev pulled from origin.