# Override local repository with remote repository

Tags: git

What do I need to enter in command line if I want to fully restore my local git repository with a specific remote repository that is not the latest? I do not want to sync/merge files but rather get old files back and delete ones that were created after the commit to which I am looking to revert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: sync local repo with remote one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373277/git-sync-local-repo-with-remote-one)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set your repository to a previous state, find one first :

```
git log
```

Find the commit you want to revert to (the commit it, something like `30cb7e27aead5ade0a8048e2459cbda63697bbac`)

The issue this command :

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

If you messed up, you can revert it like the previous command like this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@1
```

Please notice this will remove any uncommited diffs from your worktree. Commit or stash everything before if you want to keep them.

Comment: This can be done in one command like `git reset --hard origin/master` (or whatever other remote and/or branch).